# The many usernames of SFF.SE

Tags: discussion, users

**What's the story behind your username?**

If you are one of us folks whose username is not your actual name, what is the story behind it?

I'll go first.

Comment: Uh-oh, good luck proving @MikeEdenfield is *not* a false name!

Comment: I just copied my username from StackOverflow. Prosaic as hell :)

Comment: @DVK : Short but sweet, both the story and the name!  ;-)

Comment: @Praxis, point of clarification, in my opinion,  part of *what's the story* ought to include *why did you pick it*

Comment: @ThePopMachine : I'd prefer people be able simply to contribute whatever they think is interesting.

Comment: Fun question! Why the downvotes?

Comment: @Wikis, (Not me but) I would imagine people are voting on the legitimate position that this is not on-topic for meta because it's not about questions, answers, scope, or how the site works.   (But I find that position to be no fun.)

Comment: @ThePopMachine: thank you for that explanation. If that is the case, they should vote to close rather than downvote.

Comment: @Wikis : To counter ThePopMachine's explanation, cataloguing memes and organizing movie nights are also not about questions, answers, scope, or how the site works, but meta has been used frequently for those purposes.  Therefore, there is plenty of precedence for this type of question, and they should not vote to close this without voting to close those too.

Comment: @Wikis : I suspect they are not downvoting for the reason that ThePopMachine has suggested (he is almost uniquely concerned with whether things are on-topic or not), but rather just because they are not "into" this kind of fun question.  Clearly you and I both see the value of it. :-)

Comment: @Praxis: all possible theories. But unless the downvoters explain, we can only speculate. It seems a wasted opportunity.

Comment: One person has also downvoted *every* answer. Ah well.

Comment: @randal'thor: how do you know it is one person? Each answer has two downvotes, maybe we have two unhappy campers.

Comment: @Wikis Ah, it's increased: last time I looked, each answer had exactly one; now it's exactly two. A couple of people must deeply disapprove!

Comment: @randal'thor : To each, their own.  Let's not let it stop us from doing something intended to be fun and community-building.  :-)

Comment: I would have taken my usual username (used at online game services like Xbox Live, Steam, UBI, etc) if I hadn't registered at StackOverflow first and there I found it appropriate to use my real name, even though it is a rather common one.

Comment: This question is inspiring to me.  I should start a meta post on the many passwords of SFF se...

Comment: @CHEESE : lol...

Comment: You were supposed to go first. What happened?

Comment: @EtackSxchange : I did go first.  Order the answers chronologically.

Comment: @Praxis I have searched for the word *praxis* in all 3 pages of answers. But not found an answer of yours; just comments. Maybe you had a different username when you answered your own question?!

Comment: @EtackSxchange : Don’t search for “Praxis”.  Order the answers chronologically from oldest to newest.  Look at the oldest answer.  It’s from me.  You will see an *animation* with the word Praxis.  Let me help you also by giving you a direct link to the answer: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7372/40294

Comment: Oh, I searched Praxis again and I found your answer! Sounds I skipped it earlier.

Comment: While I see guys had a lot of fun here, new answers get to *third* page of answers now. Not much chance of many people seeing them. Closing seems reasonable.

Answer (score 70):

**Someone lay me down a sick beat. We goin' ham.**

It's mid-2007, not too long ago,
when a little nerdy white boy and his buddies go,
and sign up for Xbox Live to play some videogames,
using Gears of War and Halo as a replacement for dames.

Well I'm sitting there just thinking, trying to choose a handle,
but my friends names are much better, mine can't hold a candle.
Take a look at my initials - D and R can make Doctor,
think about the wannabe gangsters I can mock-a.
Throwing round words and phrases, abusing dumbass slang,
my satirical skills will make their heads hang.

Like a flash of inspiration, the air begins to sizzle,
hammering my controller, I type "Dr D Rizzle".
But it turns out that was taken, so I go for second best,
"Dr R Dizzle" sounds just as stupid, I guess.

It's been nearly a decade now, the name was a bad choice,
but I kind of got used to it as my online voice.
If there's a lesson here, then the lesson is this;
'Don't choose an online name while trying to take the p*ss'.

Comment: Darn, I wish I could upvote twice.

Comment: I pity the foo' who downvoted this mad rap.

Comment: create an account just to upvote this one.

Answer (score 50):

I am named after the minor planet [14111 Kimamos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_minor_planets:_14001%E2%80%9315000#101) which in turn is [named after a science teacher in West Virginia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meanings_of_minor_planet_names:_14001%E2%80%9315000#101) and ***not*** the [lady in Michigan](http://www.goodreads.com/author/show/8367949.Kim_Amos) who writes romance novels under that name. (Just kidding. Actually user14111 is my real name.)

Comment: Well since your *real* name is user14111 then you're effectively excluded :-P

Comment: So the real story for you is, "Once there was this woman and this man and they loved each other very much and wanted to have a kid..."

Comment: This one made my day. :-)

Answer (score 43):

I slammed my fists on the keyboard a few times until I got a result I liked.

Comment: Lol right... what if it brought up Richard 2.0 ???

Comment: Gotta admit, it sounds like a name that came out of the 5th, like Mr. Mxyzptlk.

Answer (score 39):

I would give a whole detailed explanation for my username, but really just see the previous post, it's probably all explained over there. :)

Comment: I had a friend in grad school who, with a student library helper, spent a couple hours searching for a science journal called _Ibid_.

Comment: You mean this one? https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7412/103122

Comment: @Clockwork - I shall eventually make my way to the top answer and will then just be referencing the question itself.

Answer (score 33):

Scooby-Doo → Scooby → skooby → SQB

Comment: You learn something new everyday!  :-)

Comment: Ha! And you would've gotten away with it if it wasn't for us pesky kids!

Comment: Why not SQL????

Comment: Uh... Why does it suddenly sound like Skooba to me?

Comment: @Clockwork Not sure Y, but it might just be A shout away.

Comment: @Skooba It actually took me an hour to understand that pun.

Answer (score 32):

It is a clever disguise; my real name is Bason Schmaker

Comment: If I could put a bounty on this, I would!

Comment: Literally laughing out loud.  Thanks!

Answer (score 30):

"Slytherincess" is, unsurprisingly, a combo of "Slytherin" and "Princess".

I've had this online handle since 2002.

I first read *Harry Potter* fan fiction at a site called [**The Sugar Quill**](http://www.sugarquill.net/), and I participated in their forums. I basically liked their site, but it was very restrictive -- for example, the site would only archive fan fic with what they considered to be canon pairings -- Harry/Ginny, Ron/Hermione, and Sirius/Remus (whom the site administrators considered a canon pairing). If you questioned their restrictions, even in light conversations on their forums, your post would disappear -- that kind of BS.

<sub>Oh, and, uh ... Slytherins were definitely not welcome there, and I had felt an affinity toward Slytherin since the first time I read the first book. Why? That's a whole 'nother story!</sub>

So, yeah, things at the Sugar Quill were all around problematic. I knew I was going to have to leave the site. I hadn't yet registered at the Quill; I decided I would. I tried out a variety of Slytherin-themed names, but **Slytherincess** is the one that stuck. I left The Sugar Quill, but not before leaving silly, but harmless, messages in a few of the forums I had frequented, so I could splash my new moniker, because *someone* had to say it:  **SLYTHERIN WAS HERE**! ;)

Because I got into *Harry Potter* fandom quite early on, I was able to scoop up my username in a variety of apps, most of which are obsolete now: Gmail (I still use my Gmail account); Yahoo; Livejournal; FictionAlley, AO3; *Harry Potter* conference sign-ups; Twitter; Facebook; Pinterest; Flickr; and, yes, Stack Exchange! :)

Here's the screen-saver for my iPhone (My iPhone is named "Malfoy", for anyone interested):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing, Slytherincess!  Glad you've had a better time here than over at Sugar Quill.  :-)

Comment: "Sirius/Remus (whom the site administrators considered a canon pairing)" - you owe me a new keyboard and a glass of tea.

Comment: @DVK-in-exile -- I do, don't I? I will send both via owl post :D

Answer (score 30):

I just love cheese.  That's it.

Comment: But why is it all capitals?

Comment: @Richard : Because he *loves* it.

Comment: @Praxis - Then why no exclamation marks?

Comment: @Richard : Because...because...darn.

Comment: @Richard.  The Absense of Exclamation Marks is a Deep and Thoughtful Statement.  My love of cheese is intended to spark people, inspire them: to start sentences, not finish them.

Comment: I also like cheese. Just not enough to fully capitalise my love.

Comment: Created account just to up vote this!!

Comment: A lurker has emerged from Downbelow!  Accept my belated welcome, @Fawad.

Comment: If you take all the capitalized letters from @CHEESE's comment (TAEMDTSM) and turn them into an anagram, you get Ted Stamm. Ted Stamm was, as we all know, born in Brooklyn. Brooklyn is home to Brooklyn Slate Co. Brooklyn Slate Co. offers a very nice slate **cheese** board, and is located at 33 Bowne St, Brooklyn, NY. 33 + (the number of letters in the company's address) = 50. 50 is the number of **cheeses** made in the USA that start with the letter 'C'. C is letter no three of the alphabet, which is also the number of silver badges CHEESE currently has. This path is circular, like **cheese**.

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd Perfect until the end...I had no silver badges when I made the comment.

Comment: @CHEESE I think using "currently" gives me a Get Out of Jail Free card on this one

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd Taking the capital letters in your comment you get IGOJF.  Turning into numbers, this becomes 9714106.  Dividing this by 8, your number of bronze badges, you get 1214263 with a remainder of 1.  1st street in Brooklyn is home to 251 1st street, which has 11 stories.  11 is the atomic number of sodium.  Sodium's melting point is roughly 371 degrees K.  The year 371 began on Saturday.  Saturday was named after Saturn.  Saturn, if you include the Sun, is the seventh body in the solar system.  7 is the number of silver badges DCOPTimDowd currently has on the main site.

Comment: @CHEESE My favorite game console was also the Sega Saturn. My mind is rekt.

Comment: You really need to answer this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316515/278659

Answer (score 29):

I joined this Stack Exchange to [ask Wheel of Time questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31394/rand-althor?tab=questions&sort=newest&page=2). **Rand al'Thor** is the [main character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_al%27Thor) in the [Wheel of Time series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wheel_of_Time), and also someone I can identify with personally in many ways. Nobody else had taken that username (at the time, I didn't know usernames could be duplicated), so I used it. If it had already been in use, my second choice would have been **Aragorn**.

When the Last Battle comes to Stack Exchange, I will stand firm, my two closest friends at my side, to defend what is right against the dark forces of evil and the Shadow:

[image: Tarmon Gaidon]

Long live the Dragon!

Comment: I want to be the guy with the hammer.

Comment: -1 because Bela is the main character in Wheel of Time.

Comment: So who're are your two best friends?

Comment: @CreationEdge Mat Cauthon and Perrin Aybara, of course ;-)

Comment: if only you had finished the books...

Comment: I WILL FIGHT BESIDE YOU

Comment: "f it had already been in use, my second choice would have been Aragorn." This totally reminds me of [this excellent web comic](http://thenoobcomic.com/comic/3/) :)

Answer (score 27):

You might want to take a cup of coffee and sit down for this.

Well, it all started in 2007. The world was a much more innocent place, or was I younger and more innocent? Who's to tell?

Anyways, being on volunteer work in Haifa Israel, a bunch of my friends and I started calling each other "Freak", you know, in a cool way.

> Hey **Freak**, how's it going?
>   ...
>   Dude, you're such a **Freak**
>   ...
>   etc.

Now a bunch of the girls I knew started a mini clique of their own called "The Freaks". Being that it was now the most exclusive club, I *had* to be in it (even though I was a guy). But they hesitated, it was really harsh for me, I felt that I was one of the founding members because I had originally in on the "Freak" naming. I had even looked up a Hebrew phrasebook and found the meaning of the word "Freak" which was:

> **Moozaroot** - פריק

I was gutted, how could these girls exclude me in this little, random, meaningless but oh so exclusive club, when I was such a strong impetus of its creation? Yeah, na, I was having none of that.

So I spoke to my "sister" from the clique (who wasn't really my sister but looked exactly like me - weird huh, "freak"-y even, lol), so everyone called us siblings. After a long while we convinced them to let me into this clique (and I even owned my new moniker - "Freak Wannabe").

Now my sister and I started calling each other "Mooz" because it was just shorter and funnier sounding than "Moozaroot".

Since then, I've used Mooz, or a derivative of it, in:

- StackExchange
- Facebook
- Twitter
- Microsoft Live
- ASOIAF account
- And a myriad of online games

  - A few of my younger cousins and friends have taken the 'Mooz' post-fix to their usernames too. I've sort of got a mini clan going, tee hee.

And there you have it, a small narrative titled "Mooz".

so, the next time I act like a "freak", you will know that it's because I *am*.

---

**Why 'Möoz'?**
The '[umlaut mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%96)' doesn't actually mean anything to me, it just looks cool AF!

Comment: Why are both Moozaroot - פריק transliterated?

Comment: Great story, Mooz!  Thanks for taking the time to share it!  :-)

Comment: You’re a freak.

Comment: So next time you show up in chat, we can say, "Oh, frak, it's the freak?"

Comment: I claim with pride the distinction of having been called "a freak" in high school — ***by one of my teachers***.  Naturally, it became my nickname for the next couple of years.

Comment: @PeregrineTook Hey Freak, how are ya?

Comment: Moozaroot is actually weirdness, or freakiness. Freak would be moozar (male) or moozara (female). But other than that your story is awesome!

Comment: @LordVoldemort I think *your* story is awesome and should be told; maybe in a series of books or movie adaptations... *Oh*

Answer (score 27):

1. My user name should show that I was male, so people wouldn't have to refer to me as "he, or she, I dunno". (My real name seems to have that effect; it sounds androgynous to native English speakers.)
2. I also like science fiction, and I wanted a name that reflected that. (It's a character from Red Dwarf, in case you're wondering. My avatar is the Red Dwarf itself.)
3. And I found I have rather a tendency to make lists of everything. No matter the question; if I answer anything, it's often in list form. So, that's what I do, I make lists.

Comment: Nice explanation (in list-form, no less)! :-)

Answer (score 27):

Organic marble!  It's gluten free, absolutely no BPAs, non allergenic, and crunchy!  Contains only trace amounts of uranium!  Accept no substitutes for this all natural product!

Comment: But is it free-range marble?

Comment: Non-GMO, right?

Answer (score 26):

I'm named after a [far away moon](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Praxis).  In the year 2293 of the [Prime Timeline](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Alternate_reality), I exploded due to over-mining.  This caused an ecological disaster on my parent planet that led to two warring empires not really fighting anymore.

[image]

(**TL;DR:** I picked it because I like Star Trek.)

Comment: Kudos to @Richard for making this animation. :-)

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question.  Why did you pick it?

Comment: @ThePopMachine : lol...I didn't say why did you pick it, only "what's the story?"  A moon exploding is the story.

Comment: “I exploded due to over-mining.” We’ve all been there bro.

Comment: And here I was assuming you were a Walter Jon Williams fan.

Comment: Huh, I always just assumed you were an ethnologist or philosopher or one of those fields where they talk about praxis and theory…

Comment: There's some Blade Runner feeling to that animation.

Answer (score 24):

I stack, therefore I am. I build Lego for public display. My builder's name is *Major Stackings* and denotes the utter importance of each and every creation I put together. ;) Although I build whatever captures my interest, I'm mainly into micro scale & miniland scale MOCs ([M.O.C.s, in Lego language means *my own creation(s)*](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/135/what-does-the-acronym-moc-stand-for)), so, to me, the name *Major Stackings* is pretty funny. I use it here, because, you know, *Stack Exchange* sounds like a Lego swap meet.

---

Here are a couple of the links from BrickCon 2015:  Three theme coordinators (myself included) get interviewed http://www.breakingdads.com/all-sorted/as-pod/brickcon-2015-interviews-part-2/ and the BreakingDads.com guys explore some of the displays on video http://www.breakingdads.com/all-sorted/video/brickcon-2015/

Comment: But that's not your name now, right? Why the new name?

Comment: @Wikis I'm incognito atm. Kind of a joke until I get sent and then share a link of a BrickCon interview with my real name. Plus some of the pics from BrickCon gave my real name away. So, since it's already out there I figure I'll share once the piece gets edited and put online. Then I'll go back to my regular nic.

Comment: It might help the non-experts if you explain (or at least link) what in the world MOCs are? :)

Comment: @Axelrod Here's the link to the 2012 Lego/Sci-Fi blog I wrote way back then.  http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/10/brickcon-2012/

Comment: And here I thought you were the militant arm of the [Royal Society for Putting Things on Top of Other Things](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1f-kfRREA8M)

Answer (score 24):

I’ve been a fan of The Lord of the Rings since before everybody had heard of it:

- I read it for the first time in the late 1960s.<sup>1</sup>

  - I still have a very dog-eared and taped up copy that was printed in 1966. 
    Not a first edition, or anything, just old.
- I’ve read it cover-to-cover probably five or six times. 
  (I have bought a newer copy; the old one is falling apart.)

  - Yes, I know there are people who read it every year.
- Every now and then I pick it up and just read a chapter or two.

So I wanted my user name to reflect that.

Also, I grew up in an area where peregrine falcons are indigenous,
and I wanted to pay homage to them. 
And, of course, Pippin’s real name is Peregrin Took. 
And, of course, a “rook” is a kind of bird. 
So it all fell into place.

Also, I like chess, although I’m absolutely no good at it.
________
<sup>1</sup> Yes, I remember when telephones had “dials”. 
And, yes, we did ride dinosaurs to school.

Comment: Ha! I remember *before* telephones had dials.

Comment: I, too, remember the joys of the rotary phone! Also, pay phones on every corner, leaded gas, and drive-in movie theaters :D

Comment: Ah, yes; pay phones.  I think I saw one five or ten years ago.  And phone ***booths*** — I loved the scene in the Superman movie where Clark Kent runs up to a pay phone that's just a phone on a pole and regards it with a look on his face that says, "So where can I change into my costume?"

Comment: I'm not *that* old and I remember dial phones. I would wake up to the whirring and jarred-crunches of the dial-up modem tone; and the phrase "Get off the Internet, I need the phone" is in no way strange to me.

Comment: Ha, ha! I remember party lines and "Operator, please get me . . ." I also remember 10 cent a gallon gas and 15 cent pizza. Or was it the other way around? I remember milk in glass bottles with the cream on top, I remember zzzzzzzzzzzzzz

Comment: +1 especially for the dial phones and dinosaurs comment.  I'm only a little younger, remember when phones had dials, and no, I'm sure you did not ride dinosaurs to school :-)

Answer (score 19):

I am a competitive ballroom dancer and have a serious passion for all three types of tango, which is Argentine, American, and International.  I was originally TangoOversway since, when I first logged on, the system wouldn't let me use Tango, but found later I could change it.

In American tango, there is a move at the lower ability level (Bronze) called the Oversway.  It is, for that level, a particularly challenging move, but looks awesome if you get it right.  So combining that with the dance name seemed a good choice.

As for the different kinds of tango, my favorite (and my fiancée's, as well) is Argentine tango, which doesn't have an oversway and generally is not used in competition.  Argentine tango is just a beautiful, passionate, and sensual dance.  International tango is used mostly for competition and American tango is used for competitive ballroom, but also used for social ballroom.

What can I say?  I just love to tango!

Comment: I kept meaning to ask you if you were into dance --- now I know.  Thanks for sharing!  :-)

Comment: I always thought you were former military. The dancing monkeys make much more sense now.

Comment: Actually, they're orangutans.

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd: And, even though I was interested in the military as a teen, at this point, anyone who knows me in real life can tell you I'm about as un-military as one can get! ;)

Comment: @Tango Don't they allow dancing in the army now? ;)

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd: Maybe, I don't know.  I've never been in the Army.  The closest I came was a cadet in the Civil Air Patrol.

Answer (score 17):

If you can't figure out my real name, I'm not going to tell you.  It's pretty obvious.  If you're having trouble figuring it out, Google the word "[spoonerism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoonerism)".

Comment: Is that something like an anagram? So your real name is . . . Chew Beard? Cheer Bawd? Arch Dweeb?

Comment: @user14111 - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoonerism

Comment: @user14111 - Spoonerism:  "The lord is a shoving leopard";  "I hissed the mystery lecture".

Comment: Shouldn't that link be http://lmgtfy.com/?q=spoonerism ?

Comment: I'm... giving up.

Answer (score 16):

Back when online gaming meant telnet, I was younger.  And stupider.  I may have just repeated myself.

I was just discovering the internet when I heard about online role playing.  Friends liked MUDs, but I found myself drawn to MUSHes, which had less numbers and involved less killing harmless level 1 critters for an hour.  The biggest MUSH I found was Elendor, and it was based around Lord of the Rings (big enough that it may even still be around, I haven't checked).  So I registered an account, thinking thoughts of being Gandalf.

Everyone has those thoughts.  There's a big sign that says "book characters are reserved, don't try to make one" for a reason.  Naturally, being young (and denied), I took umbrage and for the next infinity of fifteen minutes tried to think of a character minor enough to sneak in as.  I finally came up with a name that worked to my delight.

It worked because I'd misspelled it.  I'd been aiming for Haldir.  I'd typed Hildar.  (I later turned the character into a dwarf, for amusement)

Remembering my silliness, in a later RPG that year I just rearranged the letters again, to create Radhil.  Almost by accident, I also created a character that knew many stories and how to draw the wisdom from them, something I rather desperately wanted to emulate at the time and until that moment hadn't realized or figured out how to put words to it.  It took more years still, but I did learn the trick, and still am.

So twenty years on, I still use the name.  It reminds me I can be silly and stupid at times, and also that I can learn.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to share this, Radhil!  :-)

Answer (score 14):

Sadly, I didn't have any strong convictions about a user name before I joined.  I happened to be in the process of watching Avatar at the exact moment I signed up, and I ended up typing in avatar_sully.  I'd like to say it's some sort of high-browed life imitating art thing (my user account being an avatar of me), but...no.  It was just extreme laziness.

And the silly thing is, I don't even really like Avatar.

I've thought about changing my user name, planning it out in my mind that I would go to my profile page and click that Edit button.  But I'm just to lazy to move the mouse there.

It seems right that I should be punished for my laziness by being condemned to live out my online life with not the user name I need, but the one I deserve.

Comment: You do realise you can change your user name? (And, ironically, your _avatar_.)

Answer (score 13):

The first online community I heavily participated in was a Kingdom Hearts forum, and sometime after Kingdom Hearts 2 came out there was a thread where everyone posted their Organization XIII names. For those unfamiliar with the game, the Nobodies in Organization XIII created their names by taking the names they had back when they were human, rearranging the letters and adding an X. So my real life name of "Eric" became "Ixrec".

I quickly realized that this would make a good username as it was fairly short, distinctive and had essentially zero google hits, so I've been using it consistently on every other site and community I've joined since then.

Comment: Are you sure it's not lxrec or ixrec or 7xrec or something?  ;-)

Comment: @Praxis I'm pretty sure my real life name is "Eric", not "eric" or "Er1c" or "Er7c", so...

Answer (score 13):

I actually hadn't really realized I was using my actual name for my display name, so I modified it to my preferred handle :)

Originally, I went around the Internet as Broseidon, [which I stole](http://www.vgcats.com/comics/?strip_id=285). However, that name was reletively common and I need to be a special snowflake.

So, I took [Premier Romanov](http://cnc.wikia.com/wiki/Alexander_Romanov) from Red Alert 2 and added a B to make it BROmanov. Because I'm very clever. I grew up with the *Command and Conquer* series, so it was only natural.

After 3-4 years of having my own unique handle, I've found it stolen by another steam user and now I weep every night.

Answer (score 13):

In "Heaven Sent," the 11th episode of the 9th season of the reboot of *Doctor Who*, the Doctor quotes the tale of the shepherd-boy, from the Brothers Grimm:

> There’s this emperor, and he asks the shepherd’s boy: How many seconds
>   in eternity? And the shepherd’s boy says, ‘There’s this mountain of
>   pure diamond. It takes an hour to climb it and an hour to go around
>   it. Every hundred years a little bird comes and sharpens its beak on
>   the diamond mountain. And when the entire mountain is chiseled away,
>   the first second of eternity will have passed.’

The Doctor's mountain of pure diamond is my profile picture:

[image]

Adamant is an archaic word for (among other things) diamond, [as seen](https://books.google.com/books?id=ATlnAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA24&lpg=PA24&dq=%22mountain%20of%20adamant%22%20shepherd&source=bl&ots=YEU8s4B3t6&sig=VxV6zAf_DAwbc9H214W-IGOmz6g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLpeaUye_NAhVKfiYKHRCrD6wQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22mountain%20of%20adamant%22%20shepherd&f=false) in a few versions of "The Shepherd's Boy":

> "The third question," said the King, "is: How many seconds in
>   eternity?"
>
> —To this the little shepherd-boy replied, In a remote district
>   of Pomerania there is a mountain of adamant.

Comment: Technically, what the Doctor had was not a mountain of pure diamond but a wall of *azbantium*, 400 times harder than diamond.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Nor was he technically a bird. ;) If poetic license is good enough for the Doctor....

Comment: I was thinking it was like inexorable.

Comment: So, what was your username before Adamant and Obie?

Comment: A while ago I suddenly see all these HP questions getting new, really good answers by someone called adamant and I looked at the rep and saw ~40k and I was like "how can someone have that much rep and be a HP fan and yet I've never noticed them before?" Hence my interest in what you went by before that. So, was that your username before?

Comment: @RedCaio - Yes............

Comment: wait, so did you have loads of rep before or is that a recent development?

Comment: @RedCaio - Yep, loads of rep. I did not do much until, what, April? Then I got about 25,000 reputation between then and August. I slowed down after that.

Comment: @RedCaio - Would you rather discuss this in a chat room? It is getting a bit chatty for a comment thread.

Comment: @RedCaio - [Here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46223/chat-between-adamant-and-redcaio).

Comment: "remote district of Pomerania"... If I knew there's a diamond mountain, somewhere by the sea around here, I'd go there ;D

Answer (score 12):

Way back when, when xbox live was first becoming a thing. Me and my older brother wanted to play online. We spent the night setting up the router and such (Old model even for 2005-7 or whenever it was) so we didn't actually get online that night. I go to school the next day and just come home to him playing online on some random named account and i ask why it isn't with my account.
It was my account but my name was taken and so he decided in his infinite wisdom to random name generate a new account name for me. Needless to say I wasn't happen but it has long since grown on me and spread to every corner of my internet ID. Crazy. It's actually really good considering how unique it is, it has only ever previously existed once. Stupid twitter.

Also I'm apparently some fruit with a seed in the center or something, who knew!

Comment: XBox live random names are nuts.

Comment: My best mate was DejectedApple, it's an awesome name

Answer (score 12):

I was looking for an obscure nickname for one online messaging board or another. I was playing a game called Waku Waku 7 at the time, which featured a character called Politank-Z, which was a walking tank piloted by a Mario-like character and his dog. It fit my criteria at the time: absurd, obscure (the only web search references I found to it were to the video game), and non-identifying. I have stuck with it, for the most part, since.

[image]

Comment: hey ! I played that game too ! :D

Answer (score 12):

I play world of warcraft, it has a random name generator, it gave me himarm, read as him arm, not hi marm. thank you

Comment: I will now read it properly in my head from now on.  Thanks for sharing!  :-)

Comment: Woo-hoo, I always read it properly. What do I win?

Comment: @Mooz you win not having me track you down and gut you like a fish

Comment: Great, so do I :-D

Comment: What do you mean?   It's clearly pronounced hi-marm.

Comment: For some reason, I'd always read it as being vaguely Farsi or Pashto or something along those lines. Don't know why, but I've always pronounced it [ˡçim.ɑɾ(ə)m]… so at least I guess I've been syllabifying it correctly, just pronouncing it all wrong…

Comment: I've been reading it as "Hirmarm". +1 for dyslexia.

Answer (score 12):

Like the pine trees lining the winding road,
I've got a name, I've got a name;
Like the singing bird and the croaking toad,
I've got a name, I've got a name.
And I carry it with me like my daddy did,
But I'm living the dream that he kept hid...

That's about it.

Answer (score 12):

My username is [user13267](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/13716/user13267) because it has [these properties](http://www.numberempire.com/13267)

And I promise I didn't just google it up

Comment: But, wait, you're actually user13716. Is this *serious*?

Comment: upvote the answer and may be I'll tell you :)

Comment: Upvoted due to curiosity :-)

Comment: wait this doesn't increase rep?? dang it

Comment: Nope, votes on meta have no effect on rep.

Comment: Anyway I guess I owe an answer, the name was bestowed upon me by stackexchange's RNG, and turns out it had all these cool properties

Comment: So the [cool properties](http://www.numberempire.com/13267) are *not* being a Fibonacci number, *not* being a Bell number, *not* being a Catalan, . . .? Did you know that the Bell numbers are named after a [sci-fi writer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_Temple_Bell)?

Comment: more I think about it, I think "cool" should have been in quotes

Comment: also, [14111](http://www.numberempire.com/14111)

Comment: On Arqade, you could be user[32167](http://www.heroesofmightandmagic.com/heroes2/cheats.shtml).

Comment: I liked it, because every number is special!

Answer (score 12):

My first handle was SonOfSam, which I picked because:

1. "Sam" was the first (non-gibberish) output a random-name generator I made years ago came up with, and
2. Mad Max had recently released and I like alliteration, so I thought it sounded similar and cool

I had no idea that that was also the name of a famed serial killer(!), and I felt bad about unknowingly parading myself around as a fan of his. So I did some research on him, and found out that there are two officers who are credited for arresting the Son of Sam: William Gardella, and Timothy Dowd.

Gardella went on to give presentations where he'd go over general serial killer stuff and then describe the Son of Sam case specifically.

Dowd received an almost unheard of *two promotions* for his investigative work that brought down the Son-o-Sam, going from deputy inspector to **deputy chief (DCOP)**. He retired a year later, and from what I can tell, led a pretty normal and quiet life until he passed away at the ripe age of 99.

Seeing as I'm more of the introvert type and not a stranger to rising more than one rank at a time (ladies ;)), I chose the one who wasn't putting themselves out in the spotlight, therefore,

> **DCOPTimDowd**.

---

Since I don't think I'm capable of giving an answer without any kind of cited source, here's more [info](https://www.nytimes.com/2014/12/30/nyregion/timothy-dowd-detective-who-led-son-of-sam-manhunt-dies-at-99.html) on Mr. Dowd for those curious enough.

I also like giving pictures apparently, so here's one of Dowd working on the Son of Sam case back in 1977. Pretty handsome dude, actually.

[image]

Anyway, that's my story.

Comment: Wow. Well played.

Answer (score 11):

In case you were wondering, my username is "Often Right".  Now, if you're a Trekkie and you don't know who this is then leave this site now - just joking!

Often Right is an obscure reference for [Dr Noonien Soong](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Noonian_Soong) - don't trust Memory Alpha, trust me - his name [is Noonien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/100020/is-it-noonien-or-noonian-soong).  Lore says he was known as 'Often Wrong', but I didn't like that name, so I'm changing it to 'Often *Right*'

Now, the important question: **why did I choose this handle?**  Well, there are a few reasons:

1. There is actually a striking resemblance between the real me and the character of Noonien Soong, not so much in appearance but in characteristics
2. I'm also fascinated by concepts of artificial intelligence and robotics
3. He's my favourite character from *Star Trek*

Comment: Thanks, Noonien!  ;-)

Comment: Awesome!  I always wondered where your username came from :)

Comment: Also known as Often Wrong.

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude not to mention 'The Doc' 

Comment: Time to remove that top section?

Comment: @randal'thor haha yeah - I'd quite forgotten about that. Thanks for the reminder 

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude And now, Often Right.

Answer (score 11):

Long story short, it's the combination of old nicknames, newer coined ones, and the difficulty of securing a unique username on most sites.

In my Freshman year of college, I joined a group named The Fuzzies run by [Father Matt Komescher](http://www.legacy.com/obituaries/cincinnati/obituary.aspx?n=matthew-kohmescher&pid=149581015) at the University of Dayton. We had blue buttons with the word "Fuzzy" on them and membership cards. We'd pledged to make the world a better place by being nice to people and "giving at least one warm fuzzy a day". Because I wore the pin every day, I quickly became nicknamed "Fuzzy". When I started my first job after college, I still wore the pin, but one of my co-workers kept adding to the nickname until he finally settled on a simplification of FuzzyBoots because I also occasionally wore into work a set of bright yellow Caterpillar boots.

Being a common name, Fuzzy was a difficult username to secure, so I started using FuzzyBoots on many sites.

Up until today, I was just using my name, Sean Duggan, on the site, but I figure I ought to embrace the idea of a proper alias. ^_^

Comment: Thanks for sharing, Fuzzy!  :-)

Comment: _These boots are made for fuzzin' / And that's just what they'll do_

Answer (score 11):

I'm just bleh.

Complete bleh.

Answer (score 11):

My display name on this SE community comes from a Character from George R.R. Martin's epic fantasy series *A Song of Ice and Fire*.

Most of the people who are familiar with the work assume that it's after [Aegon I 'The conquerer' Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_I_Targaryen) but in fact it is after [Aegon V 'the fortunate' Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_V_Targaryen). (Aegon I was a useless bloke who wasn't really a very good ruler).

I did toy with picking the name "Aegon the Answerer" (Because it kinda sounds like Aegon the Conqueror) but then I thought it is too weird. So Aegon it is, Seven bless our good king Aegon V.

Comment: ahhh, I *was* goiing to ask which Aegon. I had pretty much ruled out IV, because you know...

Comment: Aegon IV had a lot of fun tho lol. They can call him unworthy but that guy must have been fun to have at parties (If you don't have any female family members or friends in a radius of 2 KM)

Comment: plus he gave us Bloodraven, so can't complain too much!

Comment: With Dunk, they are one of the coolest buddy couple of the ASOIAF world !

Answer (score 11):

From the English nursery rhyme.

> Jack be nimble,
>   Jack be quick,
>   Jack jump over
>   The candlestick.

I made the decision to abbreviate my middle name.

Comment: "*[jumping candlesticks was a form of fortune telling and a sport. Good luck was said to be signalled by clearing a candle without extinguishing the flame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Be_Nimble)"* - Well, you learn something new every day.

Comment: @Valorum - and by not burning your dangly bits.

Comment: @Wikis Wonder if that "custom" ever _caught_ on in the Highlands (land of kilts and all)? <_<

Comment: @ReinstateMonica-GoodbyeSE Seems pintless to reply now, but what you mentioned, we used to say as an extra line as kids - it explains what he burned, which rhymes with -"stick". Kids lol!

Answer (score 10):

I wanted to promote an [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) initiative I created about wikis, first called *"Wikis and Wikipedia"* and then "*Wikispeedia"*. We weren't getting enough people interested so I changed my user name to *"Wikis at Area 51"*, an initiative which delivered zero impact.

When our Area 51 proposal died, I shortened it. I might change it again; searching for *"Wikis"* (eg in [Mos Eisley](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley) or even [here on meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Wikis)) is pretty hopeless: most of the time people are talking about Wikipedia. :)

Comment: It makes me think of the main character in *District 9*... Though, obviously spelled slightly differently

Comment: @Catija: indeed, I nearly added that!

Comment: @Wikis, I don't understand what this proposal would have been

Comment: @ThePopMachine: maybe that's why it wasn't a success?! It was a place to discuss things like how to implement a company wide wiki, how to work with software extensions, which wiki software to choose etc. BTW, will you explain your user name?

Comment: @Wikis, ah got it.   This is now an answer in a wiki comment about a question in a wiki comment about meta-wiki answer by Wiki-named user about a wiki site proposal about wikis.     This is some serious *Inception* s#*t.

Comment: @ThePopMachine: and I popped over to my machine to pop a message to your machine via the Stack Exchange machines while drinking pop. I need a lie down.

Comment: Seeing all the great examples on this page, I really wish I'd thought of a better name...

Answer (score 10):

My user name, RedCaio, is inspired by my real name.

- "Red" is part of my last name.
- "Caio" is a Portuguese name that, when said aloud, sounds like "Kyle", which is my middle name. I speak Portuguese so I thought it was neat.

I've used CaioRed and RedCaio interchangeably on different sites. You'll notice my profile has links to my QueekyPaint and YouTube accounts, the usernames for those are CaioRed and RedCaio respectively.

Coincidentally, now that they've made a new Star Wars film, I noticed that CaioRed sounds a little bit like "Kylo Ren", hence [my avatar/profile pic](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7681/the-many-avatars-of-sff-se/7736#7736)! 
O.O

Comment: Thanks for this, @RedCaio!  I'm going to think "Kyle" from now on when I see your username...

Comment: Oh, I always thought you were Portuguese. Sneaky tricky!

Answer (score 10):

I usually go with the name Spicy Wiener or swissdude323 (123 was taken). But after finding I really enjoyed Tolkien's world and becoming a regular on the Tolkien subs on reddit, I decided I needed a Sindarin name, so I chose **Edlothiad**.

> edlothiad ger. of edlothia- **blossoming, flowering** <- edlothiand WR/293 Actually, edlothiand might be a misreading, according to David Salo who checked the original manuscript at Marquette and reported that his reading was unmistakably edlothiad.

I chose this name because my love for Tolkien had just begun to blossom and I wanted to nurture it. I also thought the name was very cool sounding, and the nickname Ed was very applicable.

Comment: ..."123 was taken", bahahaa, I lost my shit!

Comment: @Möoz the truth don’t lie

Answer (score 10):

My user name, TheLethalCarrot, is taken from my [gaming name](http://steamcommunity.com/id/TheLethalCarrot/) used on all new communities I join.

It used to be TheLethalCoder which was an extension from the above as I had originally joined Stack Exchange on Stack Overflow and so wanted to change it a bit to be more appropriate, it still is that on most sites.

However, recently @Edlothiad informed me that there was a charcter in A Song of Ice and Fire called Carrot and so I updated back to the original:

> Carrot, you'll have charge of their chests and boxes.

Comment: Woohoo, shout out to cha boiiiiiiiii!

Comment: @Edlothiad You're SFF Famous!

Answer (score 8):

When I was named, my parents searched for a name that wouldn't get abbreviated.

They failed.

Comment: My first name is Julie. Invariably, everyone I know calls me "Jules". I like it! I don't mind at all.

Answer (score 7):

Boring answer for you:

My user ID **used** to be my real name, but, as we got bigger, I decided to put at least a LITTLE bit of obfuscation between me and any random trolls / web-spiders, etc., and I switched to my initials.   Years ago, I tried to buy the domain of my initials (khw.com), but there's someone with the same initials who had the same idea and has been sitting on it for 10 years or so.  (No web page there,  just 'under construction', but I can't really criticize, as I rarely have anything on my domain, either.  Just temporary pages I put up for one thing or another.)

So, I bought the next best thing, to my way of thinking.. k-h-w.com.

**Sigh** -- do you KNOW how many sites don't think that's a POP3 compliant format?  Bah.

Regardless, I've had the site for years, now, tho, so when I decided to remove my actual name k-h-w seemed the obvious choice.

Comment: Thanks for this, @K-H-W!

Answer (score 7):

I can't go through all of the answers yet because I've burned through my votes and I want to be able to do them justice as I read them. But it's a fascinating thread and when my votes kick back in, I'll be back to reading everyone's reasons.

That having been said, my story is simple, if a little mushy. rosesunhill is my newish user name on a lot of sites. My name is Michael Hillel Roseman, I have two sons, so rose-sun-hill, allowing for a little mutation in the middle part. It's easy for me to remember and I've yet to find it taken on a site. I dread that day.

Now I'm thinking of painting a thumbnail that represents the handle.

Comment: Thanks for sharing!  I was actually wondering how to parse your username (e.g. "rose-sunhill" or "roses-unhill").  Now I know!  :-)

Comment: @Praxis - My pleasure! Yours, I deduced, being a good Trekkie.

Comment: @rosesunhill The word Praxis is found [all over the place](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/99721/31394), not just Star Trek. But of course *our* Praxis is a Trekkie through and through :-)

Comment: I’ve been wondering this ever since you joined the site.

Comment: @amaretto - Really? I guess I need that thumbnail. I hope it's not like "The Oneders." Don't tell me if it is. I think.

Comment: @rosesunhill I just couldn’t parse your name correctly, as evidenced by my guessing your gender wrong yesterday... :-|

Answer (score 6):

It's a bit of nonsense poetry from the album "[Who Can I Turn To Stereo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1pP5flx6MtA)" by experimental music project [Nurse With Wound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nurse_with_Wound). For a while it was the band's only album on Spotify, and when I first listened to it, it was just about the weirdest thing I'd ever heard. The dadaist lyrics and song titles really stuck in my mind. The first track, "Tune Time Machine", includes the wonderful wordage:

> A great, armed mass of darkness fish was approaching. I had the girl, the records, and the jeweled knife, but he had the time machine.

Later on the album, there's an instrumental track titled "[Approaching Darkness Fish](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yzwro80aaks)", followed immediately by the brief "Darkness Fish", making this cthonic creature an icon of sorts for the album in my mind.

There's no intended connection to science fiction (I chose the name while I was still more active on StackOverflow), despite the lyrics' references to time machine. It's just a weird blurb of absurdist humor from an obscure musician I like.

Comment: Now that's what I would call a cool name!

Answer (score 6):

It's my actual name. I never knew why Neo although I suspect that it's related to the Matrix which came out precisely one year before my birth. My mom always loved that movie.

Comment: That's a cool name

Answer (score 5):

The entertainment/arts-related sites make using your favorite characters from the respective medium/genre an obvious choice, in contrast to some lame real-life name or a username used everywhere else on the internet anyway. But since I'm not much into written works I did not want to pick a character that I have to feel hypocritical for not knowing its base material inside out. Neither did I want to be the 5000th *l0rd_vad3r* or *Gandalf87*.

Being more into movies in general than science-fiction or fantasy per se, the obvious choice were *original stand-alone science-fiction/fantasy movies* that also work as mere cinematic experiences apart from the science-fiction/fantasy appeal alone. This is the reason why I first chose *Sky Captain* as an avatar, a great character from a very entertaining and unique retro sci-fi movie. I then later changed it to another great character from one of the best science-fiction movies of recent times and left it at that.

Answer (score 5):

My username is the child of pure creativity.
When I was in my early teenage years I liked to read Naruto mangas.
Naruto's father, was the 4th hokage of the leaf village. And he was super cool. So I started using the username Yondaime everywhere on the net, which translates to 4th in Japanese. Till one day, I had the dreaded message informing me that the username Yondaime is taken, and it suggested Yondaime008 instead.
And I was like, hey look, you'd look like the next spy to 007 with a licence to kill, which is nice but also I was born on the 8th.
This website -which i forgot- actually did the creative part for me. Sorry to dissapoint you all who are reading this.

Comment: But, erm… _yondaime_ (四代目) doesn't just mean ‘fourth’ in Japanese, does it? It means ‘fourth generation’. ‘Fourth’ in its own would be 第四目 _daiyonme_, wouldn't it?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet you're absolutely right. This was an inherited misconception from badly translated mangas I guess.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a maniacal supervillain who [**hates**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2zhPhow2EGE) that hedgehog!

Comment: Or do I Hog that Hedge Hate? I can never remember...

Comment: [Alexander Robotnick - "Fun Fare"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cUrKE_ktTXI)

Answer (score 5):

Long ago, I used to use [Number 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_Six_(The_Prisoner)) (or variations as it often wasn't available) as an alias on various places.  Often, even after I gave that up, when the name I did choose for an e-mail address or whatever wasn't available, instead of tacking a 1 or a 01 on it, I'd throw 6 at the end.

A much more recent long-ago, I'd become a fan of Brian Stableford's "Star Pilot Grainger" series (also called the [Hooded Swan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooded_Swan) series), and, even more than most books, I had trouble finding anyone who'd ever read it.  So, aroundabout when Firefly came out, I started using StarPilotGrainger as an alias, specifically on a few Firefly sites and some more generic SF sites, in part with the hopes that somebody would recognize the series.  It never happened.

Around the tail end of that I was seeking a new name for Xbox Live, and figured that Grainger was too obscure to want to bother explaining if anyone asked, but wanted to keep some of that vibe, I came up with the idea of putting together the two old names and just being StarPilotSix, like I'm some anonymous pilot that's backing up the main characters in any old space opera show or movie.  And I stuck with that name through a few sci-fi related sites.

Comment: +1 for being pro-backup

Answer (score 5):

I came up with my Internet handle when I was 9. It's literally just "F1-crazy", as in, "crazy about Formula One", which I was (and thankfully, I still am). "F1Crazy" looked weird somehow, so I spelled it with a K instead. I quickly grew attached to the name and have been using it ever since. If you see an F1Krazy anywhere on the Internet, chances are that's me.

Answer (score 5):

Back when I had to commute almost two hours to work it felt like I was riding with Zombies and I was becoming one. Thus the commuter became the Zommuter. Yeah, I'm sometimes zynical. Fortunately a friend drew me [a more optimistic avatar](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12134/769).

[image]
Around minute 8:40 of [Shaun of the Dead](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/shaun_of_the_dead/).
Fittingly enough, the music playing is [Zombie Nation's Kernkraft 400](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ujhj7mfvIQk).

Comment: For some strange reasons, that avatar of yours reminds me of Jonathan Coulton's music, _"RE: Your brains"_

Answer (score 5):

I don’t know. [Everyone seems to hate whatever I write](https://hitchhikers.fandom.com/wiki/Vogon_poetry) anyway.

<—- see?

Years ago I was posting on a political forum and for some reason people started writhing in pain whenever I told them what was wrong with them. So I did a genome test and found I was dropped off on a doorstep one day from a passing Vogon freighter (yeah, I was lucky I got my security clearance, because I was able to see some of the Area 51 files). Anyhow, I thought I’d carry on my family legacy. Vote if you care - or are still alive to.

Answer (score 5):

> Jack be nimble,
> Jack be quick,
> Jack jump over
> The candlestick

Too much Jack is a bad thing. That is why it is **BEST** to take **JACK** in **MODERATION**.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that people expect you to do jack

Comment: @Valorum Jack is as Jack does.

Answer (score 5):

I was playing a retro-futuristic/cyberpunk game. At some point, two Non-Player Characters (NPC) were interacting on a forum with a play of word. I liked the nickname so much that it stuck.

[image: The game is Shadowrun: Dragonfall. Two characters are talking over the Shadowland BBS, some kind of online underworld forum for mercenaries. One of them, named "The Smiling Bandit", is asking someone else: "Always running, eh CW?". The other one, named Clockwork, replies: "Like clockwork!". There is a pun, because in the shadowrun universe, when a "shadowrunner"/mercenary is "running", it means they're working. Clockwork's reply on the other hand is more a reference on actual kinetic clockwork mechanism which are always running, and the idiom that goes with it.]

Answer (score 4):

When I was a kid, I use to write video game guides, and I was pretty good. When I started playing World of Warcraft, I wanted a more universal name to use for everything, especially my contributions to Wowhead.

My main character was a Warlock, and I specialised in Gnome Engineering. My creative mind came up with GNome ENgineer warLOCK, but Gnemlock just sounded a lot better.

I pretty much use this name, everywhere, now.

Answer (score 4):

My name is my initials (RDF) combined w/ my college nickname of "Fozz" (after Fozzie Bear, due to my combination of hirsute appearance and love of groan-inducing humor). If you see an RDFozz elsewhere - that's probably me - I've never failed to get the name on any site where I've asked for it, and it's always my first choice.

Answer (score 4):

My real name, Stefano, has Greek origins and means "crown".
Sekhemty is the name of the ancient Egyptian double crown; I always had an interest in history, ancient and medieval in particular, and I chose an username that reflected these two things.

I used this nickname on the Internet since, well, always.

It is often misspelled as Sekh*empty*, a somewhat annoying accusation of being a hollow person.

Answer (score 4):

## DisturbedNeo

*Disturbed* - Nu-Metal band formed in Illinois in 1996. Theirs was the first metal I heard and they, alongside Linkin Park, played big roles in developing my music tastes throughout my teens. I would not enjoy the music I do without them, and so they will always hold a special place in my heart.

*Neo* - Main Antagonist of *The Matrix* series, with *The Matrix* being my favourite Sci-Fi, possibly even my favourite movie, of all time. It played a big role in the development of my taste in movies, and probably fashion, if my trench coat and assortment of black clothing is anything to go by, and so also holds a special place in my heart.

The name formed one fateful day during my youth. I was trying to think up a new name for an online game, and I wanted a unique name free of numbers and those godawful "Xx...xX" things you see all over online games. Whilst pondering, my mother noticed my plight and suggested "Why don't you take two things you like and put them together, like your favourite band and movie?" And thus DisturbedNeo was born. It has been my main online handle ever since. Thanks, mum.

Comment: "Antagonist"? I'm not certain if you're confusing the term, or being clever about it.

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to think of a random name for use on the SE network, and I decided to pick a fairly common name (on stackoverflow) - a type of variable that has only two values (a *Boolean* value.) Of course, when it comes to the sci-fi SE, I'm unique (as I'm the only one on this branch of SE!)

Answer (score 3):

I am the one true king of the Seven Kingdoms.

Comment: There shall be no confusion on this point from now on.  Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Stannis is an usurper and wields a fake lightbringer. Aemon Targaryen knew that, it held no heat. You ser, don't deserve to sit on the iron throne.

Comment: He is no more...

Comment: @Ankit Show heathen.

Comment: I wonder if people dislike this name or your claim to be the "one true king of the Seven Kingdoms"...

Answer (score 3):

I'm not using my usual username, because I need to protect my identity...

Well, really...

Comment: Are you Batman?

Comment: @Richard: Errrr..... Possibly...

Comment: @Richard No, he's Spock.

Comment: @randal'thor - The childcare expert?

Answer (score 3):

This is a username I've used for many years, most actively on here and on Twitter, where I spout all kinds of inane drivel :-) The origin of my name is simply my surname and the squad number of my then-favourite player which I once got on the back of a football (soccer) shirt :-)

Answer (score 3):

I've used Marakai for... it must be decades now. Heard it yoiks ago, when a tour guide gave it as the name of a huuuuuge saltwater croc up on the Catherine River in the Northern Territory. You can see why I thought it'd be a cool name. :D It's apparently a Melanesian/Micronesian word - not Aboriginal or of the people of Arnhem Land. Sounds good, though.

No, my profile age isn't real either. As Aragorn said "I'm older than I look."

Answer (score 3):

My username is "Stormblessed", from the name people in his squad called Kaladin in *The Way of Kings*, "Kaladin Stormblessed". Goes with my avatar because he is forced to fight in the same war as House Kholinar’s troops and (*The Way of Kings* major spoilers)

> joins them, eventually

Answer (score 3):

My name is Niffler. You want to know why? Well it's because they're so darn cute!

If that isn't adorable I don't know what kind of <s>person</s> creature you are.

Comment: I love Nifflers! They are the cutest creatures in *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* - I love how they are attracted to shiny things and are constantly trying to collect treasure. In *Order of the Phoenix* a Niffler tries to steal Pansy Parkinson's gold watch during a Care of Magical Creatures class. Great name!

Answer (score 3):

*Amarth* was an evil necromancer character I made for a *very* old "rogue-like" Tolkien-based PC game Angband, and later on a similar necromancer in Diablo 2. It's been my recurring gamer name since back in the days.

It was picked at a whim while I were browsing through Tolkien's Silmarillion and it simply means "Doom" in Sindarin. Most famously in *Amon Amarth*, Mount Doom, the volcano where the One ring was forged. A fitting (though admittedly silly) name for a necromancer.

Now as it happens I'm from Sweden and there's a somewhat famous Swedish death metal band named Amon Amarth. So everyone thinks I took the name from them and that I'm a fan, though neither is true. I simply took it from the same original source as them - Tolkien.

Answer (score 3):

Tuor from Tolkien's Legendarium is my favorite fictional character

Answer (score 2):

I took my username from one of the characters in the John Knowles novel, A Separate Peace. Loved the book when I read it, as a teenager, and admired the character Finny/Phineas. We both have the habit of passively listening to what is going on around us while focusing on something else, then replaying/recalling it later. Anyway, whenever I tried to sign up for something online using Phineas it was always taken, so I spelled it Phyneas and the usernames were generally open, so it stuck and I've been using it for almost everything (online) ever since.

Comment: Wow!  I've been wondering it if was *A Separate Peace* reference, as it's one of my favourite novels!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Fell in love with Black Library books ever since they started making em a long time ago... Fell even more in love with the works of Dan Abnett. His Inquisitor trilogies, Comics, Titanicus book, First and only series etc. is what makes me come back for more and more. One name stuck with me ever since I read it first time "Cherubael". So that is when I started using it as my nickname on the internetzz... As time passed by and my brain cells evaporated Cherubael became Cherubel.

Answer (score 2):

It is just a nickname from my friends and family... there is no meaning or secret reference.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of both my initials and "Penguin". Incidentally, idea for my avatar came first as it appeared on the image bit of the "Life at a glance" bit on Windows 10 while I was trying to think of a username.

Answer (score 0):

### EXTERMINATE! EXTERMINATE! ***EXTERMINAAAAAATE!!!!!***

Answer (score -1):

I just played with the phrase Stack Exchange.

Comment: [I did not see that coming.](https://media.tenor.com/bD9vHNiR1rQAAAAd/boom-mind-blown.gif)

Answer (score -4):

The SS part of my username is the abbreviation of my real name.

The numeric part `3.1415926535897932384626433` is the value of ratio of circumference to diameter of a circle. In reality, this value is infinitely long, but I had to trim it down to 25 post-decimal digits because of the limitation of Stack Exchange. I picked this ratio because I was always interested in it. Also, there's a supernatural kind of thing attached with it. When I was kid, I realized I already knew certain things like speed of light is fastest. The value of ratio of circumference to diameter of a circle being infinitely long was also among them.

The entire username signifies that the mystery of SS is infinitely long just like ratio of circumference... oh, leave it.

Comment: What about the anagram part? ;-)

Comment: You do know that pi = 3 for small circles?

Comment: It's not your name anymore!

Comment: Super Saiyan Pi