# The many avatars of SFF.SE

Tags: discussion, users

As a sequel to [The many usernames of SFF.SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7371/the-many-usernames-of-sffse), this is the definitive collection of **SFF.SE users' profile pictures (avatars) and their meaning or significance**.

There are some of our most active users whose avatars I've always been curious about. So I thought I'd create this thread for everyone to post answers about their pics.

Comment: `There are some of our most active users whose avatars I've always been curious about.` I'm curious to know who?

Comment: @Mooz I was thinking of Slytherincess when I wrote that, although there are quite a few others (such as Jason Baker and yourself) whose avatars aren't obvious!

Comment: Funny, I *thought* you were wondering about Slytherincess' avatar! Also, [Mine is Tiesto's Nyana bird](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/21267/mooz?tab=profile)

Comment: @Mooz Ah yes, I knew you'd said somewhere what your pic was - hadn't realised it was mentioned right there on your profile! Fancy posting an answer?

Comment: As I mentioned in chat, the artist who designed the piece ("Kerli") is named [Natalie Shau](https://www.pinterest.com/jnhoulihan/natalie-shau/) (Links to Pintrest gallery). I liked the green color (Slytherin) and the designs on the girl's arms -- maybe they're tattoos, which would be cool. I also liked the steampunk/gothy feeling of the piece. So I made an icon out of it! I'm surprised there was even some interest in my icon. :)

Answer (score 26):

Pretty basic, just my logo. The logo is CE (backwards E), based on the standard image for power buttons.

## Current:

[image: Web Head]

### Base:

[image: Base CE logo]

---

I've also did monthly avatar changes for awhile:

### 2017

January-ish:
I cheated and reused January's from last year.

This February is a square, because my son turns *4*, and it's red letters because that's currently his favorite color:
[image: February 2017]

April-Whenever. I graduate from university in a couple weeks, so got my cap and school colors going on. (Last semester stuff is why I've not had time to update, but this weekend I *really* want to procrastinate, so ta-da!):
[image: Graduation 2017]

### 2016

A snowflake for January (Re-used in 2017):
[image: January 2016]

A missing image circle with the line through it, since I haven't had time to make February-themed one:
[image: February 2016]

A green one for Spring, which officially starts on March 20th this year:
[image: March 2016]

April showers:
[image: April 2016]

May flower (It's my attempt at a wild daisy, very common in my area!):
[image: May 2016]

June sunshine:
[image: June 2016]

July patriotism:

[image: July 2016]

Fall colors (technical issues and busy semester have made it hard to get anything out lately):

[image: August 2016]

### 2015

Xmas colors for December:
[image: December 2015]

Comment: I always thought it was a G. :-$

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That works just as well, for me, as my name starts with a "G" ;)

Comment: Ah, I've been waiting a month to see if you were going to have a May flowers theme.

Comment: @anaranjada I wasn't sure I would. Vector art is not my strength, and neither are flowers. This was my most challenging one yet.

Comment: ooh, the july one is awesome!

Comment: I like may, maybe because I from that month only ;)

Comment: I opened this question unsure of its value on the meta site, but I do like the explanatory part of this answer. I have to complain, though... February was not [ISO 3864-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_symbol#International_standards)-compliant. VERY DISAPPOINTING (not really)

Comment: @Pops Artistic license!

Answer (score 21):

Once I was Simon Waterson, a college football star who was transformed into a frog by a slighted witch. Then I picked up a sliver of Mjolnir, and was granted the power of Thor.

[image]

Now I am **Throg**, the Frog of Thunder. Evildoers beware.

---

I learned about Throg a few years ago, and it was (and remains) one of the funniest concepts I've ever heard; it's completely bananas, I cannot get enough of it.

And yes, I call my dupehammer Frogjolnir (the real in-universe name of Throg's mini-Mjolnir, because there is a god and he works at Marvel Comics).

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/73rJM.jpg

Comment: @Richard Cheers

Comment: Great work on the 100K mate, CONGRATS!!! Your hard work is noticeably returned.

Comment: It's Captain Ginyu!

Comment: [Thanks, frog. Throg.](https://vimeo.com/62218296)

Answer (score 18):

At the time of posting this answer, my current profile picture is a photoshopped version of my Twitter pic, courtesy of @MikeEdenfield.

[image]

It is something of a running joke at this stage that I hate everything thanks to my vocal dislike for *Man of Steel*, with other negative opinions of sometimes popular things only cementing my status as the SciFi.SE and Movies.SE "resident hater" - unearned, in my opinion, but it has stuck nevertheless.

In response to this, @MikeEdenfield took a copy of my Twitter picture and photoshopped it to mute the colours and include a *Man of Steel* poster, as well as changing the colours of the shield on my T-shirt to match those of the Steelers - an American Football team supported by @steelerfan.

After I referred to the picture as the anti-Dr R Dizzle, @randal'thor named this abomination [Elzzid R Rd](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26158705#26158705). Elzzid R Rd loves everything regardless of if it is any good or not, and is a huge fan of *Man of Steel*, which he considers to be "really deep, y'know?".

Comment: just FYI: the shirt is black because black & gold are the steelers main colors

Comment: Its my favorite answer on this meta, i did made my own entry to which make zero to no sense :D

Answer (score 16):

**Update:** My new avatar is a simple red & white "RC" for RedCaio. I made the RC as a watermark for my videos that is post on my [RedCaio youtube cannel](https://youtube.com/user/redcaio).

Icon:

[image: RC icon]

Full logo:

[image: RedCaio logo]

---

**Past Avatar(s):**

My avatar was a minimalist drawing I drew myself depicting Kylo Ren:

[image]

I am a passionate *Star Wars* fan, so I [draw](http://www.queeky.com/artist/caiored) Star Wars stuff for fun.

Comment: I didn't know you were an artist! Have you heard of the [Arts & Craft proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77518/arts-and-crafts)?

Comment: Yes, that's what we've been calling it since 1981.

Comment: ...except it's not anymore.

Comment: @Mithrandir updated :D

Answer (score 15):

My [username](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7378/31394), Rand al'Thor, comes from the main character of the [wheel-of-time](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wheel-of-time) series of fantasy novels. Originally my avatar was one of SE's auto-generated ones, but during the 2014 Winter Bash I wanted to have a real picture on which to wear my hats. The first one I went with was [the image found in my username post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeWA2l.jpg), which epitomises the WoT series in a way (Rand, Mat, and Perrin standing with their armies against the Dark One), but then I settled for this picture, which I've always found amusing:

[image: me]

<s>(I'm considering changing my avatar some time soon, by the way.)</s> I changed it! That crown, and the reference to a British patriotic slogan, were making me too uncomfortable.

[image: new me]

Comment: _"changing my avatar some time soon"_ - I like your definition of "soon" :)

Comment: @Gallifreyan I only said "considering"! I changed my mind :-)

Comment: I like the new picture! Very dramatic. I just don't understand the "British patriotic slogan;" "Keep calm" is a global t-shirt phenomenon. (Unless there's something that I'm missing, as an American.)

Comment: @Shokhet Before it became a tee shirt print, it was a poster produced by British government during WW2 ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keep_Calm_and_Carry_On) to the rescue!)

Comment: @Gallifreyan Wow. I didn't realize it was that old!

Comment: I haven't noticed this before, but your new avatar has a crown as well... on your head.

Comment: @TimE.Lord That's the Crown of Swords, I assume. *I ain't got no quarrel with the King of Illian; no King of Illian ever called me n\*\*\*.*

Answer (score 15):

I use artistic depictions of [a-song-of-ice-and-fire](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-song-of-ice-and-fire) characters as my avatar.

#### Characters I have chosen as my avatar so far (Current one in bold)

1. [Daeron I Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Daeron_I_Targaryen)
2. [Rhaenyra Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Rhaenyra_Targaryen)
3. [Daenerys Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Daenerys_Targaryen)
4. [Visenya Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Visenya_Targaryen)
5. [Elmo Tully](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Elmo_Tully) (I am not kidding, Elmo Tully, his grandfather [Grover Tully](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Grover_Tully) and his son [Kermit Tully](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Kermit_Tully) are real characters)
6. [Tywin Lannister](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Tywin_Lannister)
7. [Daenerys Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Daenerys_Targaryen) again
8. [Cersei Lannister](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Cersei_Lannister)
9. [Lyonel Baratheon](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Lyonel_Baratheon)
10. [Larra Rogare](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Larra_Rogare) with young Prince [Aegon](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_IV_Targaryen) (Later King Aegon IV)
11. [Brynden "Bloodraven" Rivers](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Brynden_Rivers) (Prior to his battle with his half-brother Bittersteel)
12. [Rhaena Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Rhaena_Targaryen_(daughter_of_Aenys_I))
13. [Robert Baratheon](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Robert_I_Baratheon)
14. [Rhaegar Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Rhaegar_Targaryen)
15. [Rhaella Targaryen](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Rhaella_Targaryen) (Using one of the images for Cersei and edited by Good people of internet into a Valyrian)
16. [Visenya Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Visenya_Targaryen) (Again - Coat of Arms Split into two because her Mother was a Velaryon and father a Targaryen)
17. [Maekar I Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Maekar_I_Targaryen)
18. [Daenerys Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Daenerys_Targaryen) - Again
19. [Aemon "*The Dragonknight*" Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aemon_Targaryen_(son_of_Viserys_II))
20. [Daemon Blackfyre](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Daemon_I_Blackfyre)
21. [Ashara Dayne](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Ashara_Dayne)
22. [Aerys II Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aerys_II_Targaryen)
23. [Margaery Tyrell](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Margaery_Tyrell)
24. [Oberyn Martell](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Oberyn_Martell)
25. [Aegon I Targaryen](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_I_Targaryen)
26. [**Elia Martell**](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Elia_Martell) with her children Aegon and Rhaenys.
27. The three heads of the Dragon who started it all - [Rhaenys](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Rhaenys_Targaryen), [Aegon](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_I_Targaryen) and [Visenya](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Visenya_Targaryen)

---

<sub>**NOTE:** To *embiggen* the images, click on the thumbnails in the avatar grid.</sub>

---

#### Avatar Grid

[image: King Daeron I Targaryen 11th Feb 2016 - 7th August 2016]
[image: Queen Rhaenyra Targaryen 7th August 2016 - 5th September 2016]
[image: Queen Daenerys Targaryen 5th September 2016 - 10th September 2016]
[image: Queen Visenya Targaryen 10th September 2016 - 3rd November 2016]
[image: Lord Elmo Tully 3rd November 2016 - 2nd December 2016]
[image: Lord Tywin Lannister 2nd December 2016 - 9th February 2017]
[image: Queen Daenerys Targaryen 9th February 2017 - 21 February 2017]
[image: Queen Cersei Lannister 21 February 2017 - 3 March 2017]
[image: Lord Lyonel Baratheon 3 March 2017 - 24th March 2017]
[image: Larra Rogare with young King Aegon IV 24th March 2017 - 1st April 2017]
[image: Bloodraven 1st April 2017 - 25th April 2017]
[image: Rhaena Targaryen 25th April 2017 - 9th May 2017]
[image: Robert Baratheon - 9th May 2017 - 28 July 2017]
[image: Rhaegar Targaryen - 28 July 2017 - 16 August 2017]
[image: Rhaella Targaryen - 16 August 2017 - 18 August 2017]
[image: Visenya Targaryen - 18 August 2017 - 23 August 2017]
[image: Maekar I Targaryen - 23 August 2017 - 29th August 2017]
[image: Daenerys Targaryen - 29th August 2017 - 6th Sept 2017]
[image: Aemon Targaryen - 6th Sept 2017 - 2nd Oct 2017]
[image: Daemon Targaryen 2nd Oct 2017 - 9th January 2018]
[image: Ashara Dayne 9th January 2018 - 22 Feb 2018]
[image: Aerys II Targaryen 22 Feb 2018 - 7 Apr 2018]
[image: Margaery Tyrell 7 Apr 2018 - 3 May 2018]
[image: Oberyn Martell 3rd May 2018 - 26 September 2018]
[image: Aegon I Targaryen 26 September 2018 - 21st May 2019]
[image: Elia Martell 21st May 2019 - 19 APR 2020]
[image: Three heads of the Dragon 20 APR 2020 - Present]

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upvote for each time you change your avatar, I can only give you one :)

Comment: I love that blue; it matches the Blue Winter Rose... (Not that I subscribe to J+D)

Comment: @Mooz, no no nooo no j+d pls :D. I like that the artist showed a younger version of daenerys which doesn't look like Emilia Clarke and is closer to her real age, even though the garb and pose is inspired by show.

Comment: I've edited it so clicking on the thumbnail links you to a full size image.

Comment: Cheers! But how? :O

Comment: @Aegon The markup you had was [![Insert text][1]][1]. The first 1 is the displayed image, the second 1 is where it links to. So by making it [1]][2] having 2 link to the full image, when you click you get the full image. I mean *Black Magic*!

Comment: Needs an update?

Comment: @Randal'Thor I might be emotional about the show right now, but not that emotional to add show characters to my 100% pure books art grid :P

Answer (score 14):

Until recently, my avatar was an "On Strike" sign.

[image]

This reflected my decision not to participate in the site's ongoing moderation (editing, flagging, voting to close/open/reopen, etc.) until the end of my unnecessarily harsh chat-ban.

Comment: Downvotes simply make me more certain that my decision was the right one to make.

Comment: Ahhh, *that's* what your strike means. I thought you were on strike completely. Cool. Good to know. Any thing I can help with?

Comment: @mooz - not that I can think of.

Comment: @ibid - I shall leave this as an archive post.

Comment: @Richard - Will you at least then leave a new post explaining the meaning behind your current avatar?

Comment: @ibid - I might do so in future.

Comment: Welcome back, Buffy! :-D

Comment: Your avatar keeps on changing, but this post does not. :(

Comment: @Richard - Can't you just copy that here? (Or provide a linkn?)

Comment: New post! New profile description!

Comment: The girl in your current avatar is cuter than the "strike" sign. But the strike sign is OK too. Who is the girl?

Comment: @fiskdal - It's Buffy the Vampire Slayer. I change it periodically. She tends to reflect my mood at the time.

Comment: @Valorum Alright, thanks! BTW, I didn't get pinged, fiskdal means "fish valley" :)

Comment: @Valorum - *The explanation is in my profile* I'm not seeing it there.

Answer (score 14):

[image: My avatar]

My avatar was Joseph Ducreux, a French painter known for breaking the fourth wall and having portraits far more expressive than the standard of his time.

A meme of the interwebs has established his paintings as the perfect place to post dated rewordings of musical lyrics. Here, we see Ducreux pointing at the camera with the chronologically correct reimagining of "Can't Touch This". It should be noted that this is not the version currently used in my avatar (the wording is different).

I abandoned my previous idea of using David Axelrod (the musician) as an avatar, as he quite simply doesn't sit still in a manner appropriate for hats. Indeed, I planned for the *long haul*.

---

In a show of solidarity with a fellow chatter... who is now a squirrel, I then changed my avatar to Vince Offer holding a Terrible Towel, with this pose, taken from a ShamWow commercial, as the base:

[image: New avatar]
I also changed my name to Terriblefan.

---

With the departure of Major Stackings and his warning against sock puppetry, I then changed my name back and changed my picture to a heavy metal sock puppet:

[image: SockPuppet avatar]

It's noted as "Metallica Sock Puppet".  While I don't care for Metallica, it is a fairly awesome sock puppet and I felt it reflected my name better than the KISS sock puppet or the Slipknot sock puppet.

---

With an avatar from Gallifreyan and a name from I Love You (because said user thought my name was Axe Lord and not Axel Rod, and making this change messed with the user's autocorrect), I have created my latest avatar-name combo.

[image: Last Avatar]

*I* think it's pretty freakin' rad.

---

In light of incidents in chat, I have changed my avatar once again, to something more appropriate to the situation.

[image: They tell you to leave then punish you when you do]

Comment: He looks so smarmy, I'm sorry, I have to DV. Thank goodness you've put hats on him, cause I can't stand to look at him otherwise.

Comment: @CreationEdge This I agree with, but any further discussion will warrant tacos.

Comment: I had to Google who that was, as I was oblivious! Hopefully when hats are over you can update this with a better av and I'll change my vote :D

Comment: @CreationEdge Hah, I'll switch over to [David Axelrod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Axelrod_(musician))

Comment: Before looking at the update, i thought it was a horse...

Comment: !!!! How can you not like Metallica?

Comment: @Slytherincess Because they haven't done anything great since the black album. :D

Comment: @Axelord - Hmm. Really? I'd argue for *...And Justice For All* as being basically good.

Comment: @Slytherincess Not my speed, but an improvement over most of the other albums inbetween.

Answer (score 14):

Back when I had more free time, I got quite interested in using [POV-ray](http://www.povray.org/) - my day job is as a programmer, and this was a way for me to use some of those skills to be artistic.

My profile pic is a cropped version of what I consider to be my nicest rendering to date, something I simply called "Ring & Ball":

[image]

While it looks simple, at the time using the processor I had available, rendering a full size image such as this took (literally) many hours - on a more modern chip it's seconds, or minutes at most!

For anyone who wants to see an example of what POV-Ray code looks like, here's a few sections from the file that defines the image.

The blue sphere at the center:

```
#declare sphereSize = 2;

sphere {
  <0,0,0>,sphereSize
  texture { 
    pigment { rgbf <0.25,0.5,1,0.9> } 
  }
  interior { I_Glass }
  finish { phong 0.9 }
}
```

The silver "bands" that encircle the red torus are defined as a single band, which are two cylinders (defined as a `cone` that doesn't taper) with a slightly smaller one "subtracted" (using the `difference` command) from the middle of a larger one:

```
#declare band = difference {
  cone {
    <0,-0.25,0>,ringWidth + 0.1
    <0,0.25,0>,ringWidth + 0.1
  }
  cone {
    <0,-0.5,0>,ringWidth
    <0,0.5,0>,ringWidth
  }
  texture { T_Chrome_5E }
  rotate x*90
}
```

This `band` definition is then iterated over and revolved around 360<sup>o</sup>:

```
#declare rot = 0;
#while (rot < 2*pi)
  object {
    band
    rotate y*(degrees(rot)+90)
    translate <ringRadius*sin(rot),0,ringRadius*cos(rot)>   
  }
  #declare rot = rot + (pi/3);
#end
```

I hope this was interesting, and gets you inspired to get making stuff!  If you didn't already find it, make sure you checkout the [POV-Ray Hall of Fame](http://hof.povray.org/) - there's some really great examples of what can be achieved.

Comment: I'm curious about your name - any relation to the famous Jim Thorpe?

Comment: @WadCheber Nope!  I'd never even heard of him a year or two ago, being in the UK - but you're not the first to ask on SE, so now I do :)  Thorpe is quite a common name over here, originally meaning small village or hamlet.  I actually grew up somewhere called Edenthorpe, with Armthorpe next door and Scunthorpe nearby too, amongst others!

Comment: Scunthorpe.  Hehe.  That has a naughty word in it.

Comment: @WadCheber Haha - yeah it regularly gets mentioned as a word that should be allowed when we use our "bad words filter" :)

Comment: That's no Ring & Ball — that's a space station.

Answer (score 14):

### Current

[image: "M" in the shape of fire flares, designed by user "Creation Edge".]

**Fire and Ice**
This is my shiny new, custom-made hotness, designed by our very own [@CreationEdge](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31178/creationedge).

It is an 'M' in the shape of flares with some of my favourite colours incorporated into it. I love that it still has that 'cool ice' feel to it, even though it represents fire; with Ice and Fire being my two elements.

### History

I've had a few iterations of the same concept for my avatar, but they have all been derivatives of [Nyanna bird logo](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=tiesto%20logo&biw=1680&bih=965&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=kuXsVO_5POe5mAWkxoHADQ&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ) of the Trance and EDM producer/DJ [**Tiësto**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ti%C3%ABsto).

1. First it was a plain black and white one (his first iteration as well):

   [image: Nyanna logo 1]
2. Secondly I had a slightly more 'modern' looking version:

   [image: Nyanna logo 2]
3. Then I followed it with a 'pink' cancer awareness themed one (which sort of stuck with me for a year or so):

   [image: Nyanna logo 3]
4. Fourthly, I had one of the most recent iterations of the logo (which was also my favourite):

   [image: Nyanna logo 4]
5. This one is great, my new favourite so far! It is a design by Erick Alvarez which I found on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/tiestomagiks/status/722866095883812865).

   [image: Nyana Logo 5]

Comment: Your avatar designs looks pretty neat!

Comment: I love a lot of Tiesto's remixes, especially his versions of songs by two of my favorite groups: Delerium and Conjure One. Good stuff. :)

Comment: @Slytherincess His remix of _Silence_ still gives me shivers when I listen to it!

Comment: @Slytherincess TIL that Tiesto has done remixes of Delerium.  I must find those.

Comment: @DavidW - Tiesto has lots of mixes on YouTube. Use one of those online programs that turns videos into audio files. Great stuff! :)

Answer (score 13):

## My avatar is a half-blown moon.

[image]

My avatar is consistent with my [username](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7372/40294).  The avatar is actually a screenshot of a screenshot.  It's what appears on the main viewscreen of the USS Excelsior near the beginning of *The Undiscovered Country*, to show Captain Sulu and his bridge crew what remained of the [moon Praxis](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Praxis) after this happened:

Comment: Looks like this moon tried to hold in a sneeze.

Comment: @creationedge - I did that once and both my eyeballs popped out of head.

Answer (score 13):

My Avatar is the lead character of my [webcomic](http://atwitsendcomics.com). His name is 'Guy'.

[image]

He's usually the funny one.

[image]

Comment: He always look cute, even when I lost the context of your comics most of the time ;)

Comment: This little Guy is so iconic, I was wondering where I've seen him before... Until I saw "Jack B Nimble" posted this, and it all made sense again.

Answer (score 12):

[image]

As my profile says, I am "[SF&F's self-styled expert on *The Thing*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/44025/wad-cheber?tab=profile)" (as of December 2015, I am [one answer away](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:44025%20[the-thing-1982]) from getting the site's first ever [the-thing-1982](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-thing-1982) tag badge).  It is my favorite science fiction and/or horror film, so my avatar is the "red smoke" version of the poster for [*The Thing*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-thing-1982), featuring the tagline preferred by director John Carpenter and producer Stuart Cohen:

> Man is the Warmest Place to Hide.

Carpenter and Cohen [despised](http://theoriginalfan.blogspot.com/2011/12/final-days.html) both the tagline and the poster design the studio opted to use: the "glow face" image and the phrase:

> The Ultimate in Alien Terror.

[image]

They felt that the "glow face" design was confusing and had nothing to do with the movie, and they criticized the tagline for giving too much away and simply reeking of B-Movie cliche.

> The advertising campaign had changed overnight - the somber, predominately black and white imagery (which we had been consulted on) replaced overnight with the now familiar "glow face" (which we hadn't), the tag line " Man Is The Warmest Place To Hide" dumped for "The Ultimate In Alien Terror", which I abhorred ("Man" was written by a publicist named Stephen Frankfort, who also came up with what I thought was the best tag line ever for ALIEN - "In Space, No One Can Hear You Scream".  He was hired early on and his company also created the earliest teaser with the ice block. The "Alien Terror" tagline was concocted by a studio suddenly desperate to display the word "Alien" above the title). Both, I thought, represented a last minute demotion to "B" film status, something we had fought for years, and evidence that Universal was effectively throwing in the towel in trying to reach a broader, more mainstream audience.
>   - Producer Stuart Cohen on his blog, [*The Original Fan*](http://theoriginalfan.blogspot.com/2011/12/final-days.html)

I agree with Cohen and Carpenter regarding the taglines, but I like the "red smoke" poster slightly more than the black and white one they wanted to use:

[image]

I think the "red smoke" version conveys a sense of the movie's plot without giving anything away.  It also scores points for featuring the superior "Man is the Warmest Place to Hide" tagline; I only wish it didn't *also* include the schlocky "Ultimate in Alien Terror" tagline.

Comment: Ha! Never realised you liked John Carpenter's: *The Thing*. That's what I'd say if I never realised you liked John Carpenter's: *The Thing*.

Answer (score 12):

I'm boring. My avatar is myself. The one I'm currently using is me after a bike race, with a balloon-animal monkey on my back (there was a balloon artist at the turnaround point and I thought it would be fun).

[image]

Comment: So the real question is ... did you win the bike race? :-)

Comment: ^_^ Sort of. It was for charity. I went really slow so that I didn't leave my wife behind.

Answer (score 12):

Meh.........

On the day I started writing it, it was Nightwing

[image]

Don't blink, it might change into [Grumpy Dwarf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Dwarfs), [Charlie Pace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlie_Pace), [Arrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_(TV_series)), [Constantine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Constantine), [V for vendetta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V_for_Vendetta), [Jason Voorhees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jason_Voorhees), [Babadook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Babadook), [Alaric Saltzman](http://vampirediaries.wikia.com/wiki/Alaric_Saltzman), [Zach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shelter_(2007_film)),  [Groncholverine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sw6Bc.jpg), Indian gods form [molee's art pieces](http://www.moleeartgallery.com/), [Captain America (Hydra Agent)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbaJl.png), [Punisher](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Punisher)  and god knows what else. Occasionally I do use my own pictures too ( still visible in Area 51).

On the side note, My avatars are reflection of my current favorite characters mostly with some exceptions. Nightwing is my all time favorite character, not Nightwing but the whole D*** Grayson character, I even like him more then Batman. I like his continuous character development. But its not going to stick forever, so why to waste time discussing it more.

Wow, while writing it, my mind giving me more idea for my next 100s <strike>1000s</strike> of avatars but for now I am sticking with it for a while.

---

---

Due to constant hearing about that people can't keep track of my profile picture changes, I am making a log here:

[image: me][image: Dexter Morgan][image: V][image: me][image: Spartacus][image: Isaac_Lahey][image: Professor_X][image: Walter_White][image: Walter_White][image: L][image: Near][image: Smoking wolf bewakoof.com print][image: me][image: identicon][image: Z-For-Zombie][image: Hook][image: Green Arrow][image: me][image: Zero][image: Joker ( Jared Leto)][image: Babadook)][image: Constantine)][image: me]

<sub>Image source linking under processing</sub>

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I lost track of few profile picture due to using old upload methods or maybe I missed them in copy paste ;D I remember few of them, they were Jason Voorhees, Jason X and maybe Freddy Krueger , Ghsotface (Scream) etc. I even recycled few of them many times, so listing only unique ones.

Comment: You probably don't need to censor Dick Grayson.

Comment: @DrRDizzle someone said me not to use F/D words in scifi ;)

Comment: I'm sure it would be fine as part of a name. Dick is just a shortened version of Richard.

Comment: I know, just making fun of his name ;)

Comment: Technically his name is Richard! I've always like him, though, but I have a strong affiliation with part of his name (and as a kid that's always cool).

Comment: @CreationEdge But Richard is not popular part of his name.

Comment: Neither is asterisks, lol.

Comment: @CreationEdge ROFL

Comment: _Hail Hydra_ is the best ;P

Comment: +1 for Charlie Pace.

Comment: Ah, the new name....

Comment: @Adamant yeah though for some change

Answer (score 11):

My avatar is one of the first selfies I ever took:

It's just a picture of [cheese in all its glory](http://content.science20.com/files/images/not%20GMO%20vegan%20cheese%20but%20could%20you%20tell%20anyway.jpg)

But I could change it to something more like [this](http://www.dragonmount.com/forums/uploads/gallery/album_367/sml_gallery_32102_367_29610.jpg) (there's also Lambfear, Pies Sedai, Berrylain, Lemon Moraine pie...)

Comment: But is it gouda nuff?

Comment: Rind al'Thor, Lews Therin Fetamon, Fishamael, Moridinner.

Answer (score 11):

My tenth avatar is Morpheus, drawn by Yoshitaka Amano for [*The Dream Hunters*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sandman:_The_Dream_Hunters).

[image]

Some examples of Yoshitaka Amano's stunning art can be found [in this blog](http://amano-artwork.tumblr.com/).

---

- My ninth avatar is once again Morpheus, King of the Dreaming, Lord of Dreams, the Oneiromancer, Oneiros, the Sandman, King of the Realm that is Not, etc...

  This particular version was drawn by J. H. Williams III and coloured by Dave Stewart, for *The Sandman: Overture* #1. In it, Dream appears in the dream of a flower - in an according shape.

  There is an interview with Neil Gaiman from San Diego Comic Con 2013, where he explains how J. H. Williams came to be the artist of this miniseries; it starts at 5:08, but the whole video is rather entertaining, as it explains how *Overture* came to be:
- My eighth avatar was Lucifer Morningstar, Samael the Lightbringer.

  This particular image comes from *Lucifer* #65, "Morningstar pt. 3". The *Lucifer* series was written by Mike Carey, and drawn mostly by Peter Gross and Ryan Kelly.

  [The character began](http://www.dccomics.com/blog/2015/12/16/lucifer-101-what-you-need-to-know) in *The Sandman* series, where he was created by the writer Neil Gaiman and artist Sam Kieth and Mike Dringenberg. His character was inspired by Lucifer's portrayal in John Milton's *Paradise Lost* (though [I couldn't find a reference](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2552/11) for this), while his appearance was based at least partly on David Bowie.

  He is not the archetypal Devil that mingles in the affairs of mortals or makes deals with them in exchange for their souls. He is, in a sense, a refugee, who rebelled against the pre-destination of God's Creation, and was set over Hell as a compromise, since Hell is the farthest point from Heaven, where God resides.

  Over the course of 10 billion years, Lucifer grew tired of ruling Hell - specifically by the views of Hell's inhabitants - and decided to abandon it all, giving the key to Hell to Morpheus (which is expanded in great detail in *The Sandman - Season of Mists* and *At Death's Door*).

  He later resurfaced in Los Angeles (spot the irony), and established the best piano bar there - "Lux".

  Lucifer's solo comic series started after a 3-issue series titled *The Sandman Presents: Lucifer - The Morningstar Option*, where Lucifer does a favour to the Heaven's host in exchange for the Letter of Passage, which grants one the exit from God's creation.
- My seventh-and-a-halfth avatar was once again Morpheus, wearing his battle helm.
- My seventh avatar is once again a puppet of the 12th Doctor, played by Peter Capaldi. I feel that I need to commemorate his character, since Peter has announced that he's leaving the show at the end of this season, along with Steven Moffat and Michelle Gomez.
- My sixth avatar is Desire of the Endless, drawn by [Milo Manara](http://www.milomanara.it). I didn't pick it because I like the character (and I do, as with all characters in *The Sandman*), but because I find this particular rendition *breathtakingly* beautiful. Not only is it gorgeous, it also maintains the perfect balance between male and female features, which is what Desire is all about.
- My fifth avatar is once again Morpheus, Dream of the Endless.
- My fourth avatar is Morpheus, King of the Dreaming, one of the Endless. This picture is from *A Game of You*, the 4th volume of *The Sandman*.
- My third and half avatar that lasted only an hour or so was, again, Morpheus
- My third avatar was the Twelfth Doctor, playing a guitar. Taken from [Doctor Puppet](https://doctorpuppet.tumblr.com/)
- My second avatar is a puppet of the Eleventh Doctor, from the *Doctor Who* series.
  I googled for `doctor who puppet` and stumbled upon [Doctor Puppet](https://doctorpuppet.tumblr.com/); they make stop-motion Doctor Who episodes.
- My first avatar is a silhouette of the Eleventh Doctor, with a clearly visible bow tie. Bow ties are cool.

<sup>Oldest is on the bottom right - click for full resolution</sup> 
[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]  [image] [image] [image] [image]

Comment: ...I thought that that one was @Adamant's profile pic for some reason o_o

Comment: I never realised what your previous profile pic was! Always thought it was just a silhouette, rather than a specific one. +1, even though bow ties are NOT cool.

Comment: @Randal'Thor  -  it's a dangerous path you're taking. Thread carefully...

Comment: Who was the old lady?

Comment: @Edlothiad who?

Comment: Your avatar just before this one? The old lady, or what looked like the old lady.

Comment: @Edlothiad updated - is that what you mean?

Comment: No, the one you had last week wasn't the 11th doctor who in puppet form, it was a grandma, I swear. [This one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsbqKm.png)

Comment: Oh wait, was that a different doctor in puppet form?

Comment: @Edlothiad ooooh, my poor memory! Updated again.

Comment: Yeah, that's it! Hope you don't mind me fixing the order.

Comment: @Edlothiad indeed, thank you!

Comment: @Edlothiad You've just mortally insulted Peter Capaldi :-P

Comment: What was the seven-and-a-halfth avatar? I glimpsed it briefly. Looked like a snake or something?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Updated ;)

Comment: Still looks like a snake to me ...

Comment: @Randal'Thor (Sort of) [full version](http://img-cache.cdn.gaiaonline.com/2809f1e32f81429d645cfd817ebbfec2/http://i76.photobucket.com/albums/j9/a_small_place_avs/miscellaneous/Dream_2.jpg)

Comment: The many regenerations of a Gallifreyan! ;) Awesome and very fitting! ;)

Comment: @Gallifreyan Isn't something missing :)?

Comment: That first picture greatly reminds me of Final Fantasy artworks.

Answer (score 9):

Until very recently I didn't have an avatar at all, but...

> [I'm trying to start a trend of putting the Fourth Doctor's hat and scarf on other Doctors.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/30174?m=26171533#26171533) - BESW

Since I recently finished all of New Who and am currently watching quite a bit of Old Who, it seemed appropriate. So far I've put the Timey Wimey hat on the Tenth Doctor, the Twelfth Doctor, and (my current avatar) the First Doctor hiding in a Dalek shell. I'll probably change it at least a few more times before Winter Bash is over.

---

I eventually settled on the Second Doctor, Patrick Troughton, because he happens to be my favorite of the Doctors from Old Who.

Answer (score 9):

**Original** (and most often)

[image: red viper]

Which many may recognize as < SPOILER ALERT >. I just really liked the meta humor and since most fans fell in love with this character, it was just another example of GRRM butchering our dreams.

---

Next up I decided to show my love of things non-SFF and being one of the few that enjoys various types of sportsball I will be changing to one of Pittsburgh based teams logo (Steelers, Penguins, Pirates) based on their playoff performance:

**2017 AFC North Champions, the Pittsburgh Steelers (January 2018)**
In keeping with "tradition" of changing my avatar when my favorite teams make the playoffs, this Steelers logo is to support them, and not confuse people in chat... (previously used in January 2017)

[image: Steelers]

---

**2016 Stanley Cup Champions, the Pittsburgh Penguins! (April-June 2016)**

**2017 Stanley Cup Champions, BACK TO BACK!! (April-June 2017)** First time since 1998 and the first time in the salary cap era!

**2018 Stanley Cup Playoffs, #3elieve**

[image: penguin18]

Comment: So you might change to the Steelers logo at some point and desperately confuse everyone in chat?

Comment: Pfft. The Steelers? They suck. Go Bengals.

Comment: @Randal'Thor *mad laughter*  "Some men just want to watch the world burn"

Comment: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7681/the-many-avatars-of-sff-se#comment27236_9763 "desperately confuse everyone in chat"

Comment: I think you need to update this.

Comment: Huh, a fellow 'Burgher. Nice to know.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots We might even shop at the same Giant Eagle, yinz never know...

Comment: I'm down in the Whitehall borough (South Hills). You?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Over in South Fayette (Bridgeville). I find myself at the South Hills Village Mall and the Ice Castle a lot.

Comment: Ah, cool. I used to do a contractor job in the Bridgeville area, and my wife and I still regularly pass through there on our way to Hickory, where we perform with Old Schoolhouse Theatre.

Answer (score 9):

I had to think long and hard about this one, but thought what better way to group my favourite tales with an awesome -scape. So I went with the "*Tales from the Perilous Realm*" cover by Alan Lee.

[image: Tales from the perilous realm cover]

---

I took my avatar from [Emmanuel Humbert's Deviantart](http://e-humbert.deviantart.com/) page:

[image: My Winter-Scape]

Answer (score 9):

One faithful *[Draw a Bird Day](http://www.dabday.com)*, I drew a bird. I took a picture of it to upload, so I could share it on chat.

Since I had no avatar back then, I used it as my avatar.

[image: A bird]

I found it works pretty well with hats.

Comment: Nice! I didn't even know Draw a Bird Day was a thing.

Answer (score 8):

My avatar was an obvious and mandatory choice, given the existing choice of my username, as explained in [this related answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7411/23386). However, in pracitice it wasn't too easy to find a nice picture of TARS that I'd be satisfied with. This is also the reason why the actual execution of my idea to use this username was even delayed from its initial inception towards the day I got myself the BluRay of *Interstellar* and was able to capture a nice picture myself.

But even the manual capture of TARS in a fitting surroundings and a pose that emphasisizes his unique and simplistic structural form wasn't as easy as I might have expected. So I settled on a compromise, fueled by a little enlightenment: Why am I so eager to highlight his full body when avatars on these sites are usually rather face-based, especially due to the limited size of the final picture in its everyday use?

So with this insight and my incapability of finding a fitting full-body image, I just settled for a picture of TARS' "face", which is, like his whole body, [deliberately non-human](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27141/49) and [pragmatically functional](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/72390/23386). And to lighten the mood as well as highlight his nevertheless unique persona, I of course chose a portrait with the joking cue light on.

[image]

Comment: Looking more like a side door refrigerator to me ;p

Answer (score 8):

My avatar is a cropped and edited version of this very Space Age-y picture because I like Space Age-y science fiction and frankly I am Space Age-y.  This could well have been me in 1965 but it is not.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

My Avatar is an artwork of Wolf Link & Midna on a Twilight Realm backdrop from The Legend of Zelda: Twilight Princess, because I'm a massive Zelda geek and the artwork is awesome.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

My handle is Pleurocoelus. A pleurocoelus (also called [astrodon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrodon)) is a dinosaur related to the brachiosaurus.
My avatar is a picture of one with slightly modified lyrics from *[Walk the Dinosaur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walk_the_Dinosaur)* by [Was (Not Was)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Was_(Not_Was)):

Open the Door. Get on the floor. Everybody walk the dinosaur.

[image]

There's no real meaning to my handle. It was an obscure dinosaur and I wanted a handle that wasn't popularthing1234. What can I say, dinosaurs are cool.

Answer (score 7):

My avatar is a picture of myself; Dr Noonien Soong.  It was drawn by Julianna I understand.

Answer (score 7):

The chronicles of my avatars...

The first one worth mentioning was the Hufflepuff crest:

[image: Hufflepuff crest]

The Hufflepuff crest was chosen because, well, I'm a Hufflepuff. And at the beginning of my activity here, I was only active in the [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) tag, and so my avatar reflected that.

---

Around Winter Bash 2015, I changed it to an image of Mr. Spock:

[image: Spock]

I needed a head to put a hat on, and Spock seemed like a good idea on a site dedicated to Science Fiction and Fantasy. Also, something something smart something something answer questions.

---

After a while I then changed it to fit my username:

[image: Gandalf]

(My username being "Mithrandir", the name that the Elves call Gandalf.)

---

I then felt a pull to the Dark Side and updated to an image of Sauron:

[image: Sauron]

I stuck with Sauron for a while. Then out of fear of becoming a Ringwraith...

---

...it was changed to a picture of Arwen Undómiel.

[image: Arwen]

(This image is a screenshot from the poster for the *The Return of the King* movie, taken from a YouTube video playing the soundtrack.)

---

And to switch to a different universe...

[image: Isabella]

Isabella Garcia-Shapiro from [phineas-and-ferb](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phineas-and-ferb).

Screenshot from a YouTube upload of the song "Whatcha Doin'?" from the episode "Roller Coaster - The Musical".

---

And to hop franchises again, now it's Violet Parr from *The Incredibles*. Sticking with the pattern, again it's a screenshot from a YouTube video.

[image: Violet]

---

Now, to depart from the previous theme...

[image]

This is a cropped and lightened version of a drawing made by [avazula](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/4550/avazula), that is a representation of me based on things I've said in Interpersonal Skills chat. This is the full version:

[image]

Comment: A Lord of the Rings username and a Star Trek profile pic? Argh, cognitive dissonance! :-P

Comment: Well, didn't the *Enterprise* perform 'miracles'? (That was definitely mentioned in the novels that i read...) Gandalf (AKA Mithrandir) did too. :P

Comment: IMO having an avatar and username say the same exact thing is just being lazy. :-)

Comment: yes lets mix things up: http://i1.wp.com/www.blogcdn.com/www.urlesque.com/media/2010/12/dumbledoretrollq.jpg?resize=410%2C231

Comment: @user13267 Isn't it enough that my top tag is [tag:harry-potter]?

Comment: ...your current avatar is no longer Mithrandir, now is it? :p

Comment: @Shokhet - that is correct. I'll get around to it at some point...

Comment: But your hairs supposed to be shorter based on your Hat post

Answer (score 7):

Mine is a (happy)Pikachu from the anime series of Pokemon

> [image]

Answer (score 7):

I'm *Girl With a Pearl Earring*, using hats to defile Vermeer.

For anyone after WinterBash 2016;

[image]

Answer (score 7):

My older avatar was of Darth Revan, my favorite character from the old *Star Wars* EU.

[image]

I used it because I consider him the coolest of *Star Wars*' many 'rogue Jedi."

Recently i changed avatar to a poorly photoshopped collage of various things that I like.

[image]

I frequently add to it, and it currently features references to:

- *Firefly*/*Serenity*
- *Star Wars* (specifically *Knights of the Old Republic*)
- *LOST*
- Captain America
- Marvel
- *Destiny*
- LEGO
- *Doctor Who*
- The band Journey
- *Arrested Development*
- *Avatar: The Last Airbender*
- *Gravity Falls*
- *Back to the Future: Part II*

Answer (score 7):

My avatar used to be a photo of me with a sword.. Then again, my user name used to be my real-name.  When I eventually decided to go at least a LITTLE harder to track down, I changed my avatar to the symbol of [The SCP Project](http://scp-wiki.wikidot.com/), which is where I first ran across a link to this site, and where I spend entirely too much time.

A while ago, I had a badge made up for the SCP project; it uses the same original photo I had here.

[image: My SCP Badge -- yes, it's a real badge]

Answer (score 6):

My avatar is GIR with his dog costume and a mustache and a sombrero because I'm mexican and Invader Zim is one of my favorite cartoons...and I don't mind stereotypes.[image]

Answer (score 6):

My avatar is now [Aegon V](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_V_Targaryen) "Egg", in is youth with his shaved egg head.

[image: Egg]

### Former one

[image: Vault Boy]

Answer (score 5):

More minor story for this question. I was kind of on a fantasy figurine kick for a good long while, and kept trying to turn an image of one or another into an avatar. They usually sucked.

Eventually I pulled out an old Nintendo R.O.B. robot (anyone remember Gyromite? Anyone? Bueller?) and for lack of anything else useful to do with it added it to my display. It stuck out horribly among a bunch of pewter and sand castles and other kitsch, so I put a sword-in-the-stone letter opener thing in his hands, like it was pulling it out, and it just made me smile.

Took a photo, it seemed to fit, and I haven't found anything better in a while. Really ought to get a clearer/brighter picture, but its all back in storage now.

Answer (score 5):

Mine is a picture of Thomas the Tank Engine with a really angry face with the text "All aboard the rage train" which was given to me by a friend when they saw me fly into a rage at Java and Oracle's SQL client having two objects with the same type and it causing me to go "WHAT DO YOU MEAN DATE ISN'T TYPE OF DATE. THEY'RE THE SAME DAMN THING!?!?!"  and then fly into a further rant about why would they ever do that and not use the same class for both.

Answer (score 5):

The HouseKholinar crest from *The Way of Kings* by Brandon Sanderson, white-on-black to be less blinding:

[image: The Kholinar Crest from the *Stormlight Archive*.]

[Formally Corvo Attano's Mask.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXGcS.jpg)

[Formerly Emily Kaldwin from Dishonored 2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32dqI.png)

Answer (score 4):

One day in my job I just suddenly decided to draw something on the whiteboard. As I am unable to draw anything else, I draw a face.

[image: before]

Days passed.

I often need to take some photos in my job (we develop a mobile app) so I took a picture of this drawing that still was on the whiteboard (because nobody uses it at all).

Days passed.

I joined Worldbuilding and SF&F SE

Days passed.

I decided to upload some profile picture, So, I looked in my computer memory and there it was, the face. But it was during 
[Winter Bash 2016 - All Hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288271/winter-bash-2016-all-hats) 
so I needed both eyes. I changed it a little (copied eyes and ears, copied and rotated the half of mouth) and here it is (nicer than anything ;)):

[image: after]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

My avatar is just a plain and boring depiction of myself from [Face Your Manga](https://www.faceyourmanga.com/)

Comment: You look like I could capture your head for a reward from Cersei.

Comment: I'm just a bit taller than that... I don't know if she will be fooled

Comment: Can't tell someone's height from just their head ...

Answer (score 4):

My avatar is me.

This was taken in 2010, during my form presentation of my testing for 4th degree.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

My wife drew me a more optimistic version to [my nickname](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12133/769), her interpretation of a [Bookling](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Stadt_der_Tr%C3%A4umenden_B%C3%BCcher):

[image: The Bookling Zommuter]

Answer (score 3):

“Hello, it me”, as they say on YouTube. Or Twitter. Or one of those newfangled places where people say such things. So yeah, it’s just a slightly annoyingly cropped picture of me.

[image]

(I actually just realised, due to this thread, that I hadn’t uploaded my avatar to this site at all—thought I had.)

Comment: I think you forgot to actually _explain_ what you avatar _is_ and what it _means_ and all that. :)

Comment: @RedCaio That's the first sentence—it's just a snapshot of myself without any deeper meaning…

Comment: I am *so* glad you explained your avatar -- I have to admit that all this time I thought you were female! You most definitely are *not* female -- you're a very good-looking man. Are you not American? Because I was thinking "Janice" is a female name here in the US, and I was reading "Janus" as "Janice".

Comment: @Slytherincess Nope—Janus may sound annoyingly similar to Janice (depending on how you choose to pronounce it), but it's a different and quite rare name. I'm actually named after a [Roman god](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janus).

Comment: Your name has an interesting background. I also have a "J" name, but it doesn't have any kind of exotic meaning as far as I know. Anyhow, nice avatar!

Answer (score 3):

While loitering in Mos Eisley, watching on - topic chat soaring above my head, I grew jelous of everyone's avatars and looked sadly at the defult pink pattern thing the site gave me when I joined. Plus I just got a hat and it looked poo on my avatar so (like two days before hats vanished :( ) I decided I needed something better.

Having just been writing an essay on *The Metamorphosis* I hurried to Deviantart.com and shamelessly stole a surreal - looking Gregor Samsa (we're allowed to do that right?)

Comment: As long as you cite the original.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

What can I say? They look cute in hats.

Comment: where is hat..?

Answer (score 3):

***‹ Sigh ›***
I suppose you'll be wanting me to reveal my own right name too?

Well, I guess one answer here is as good as two.
My icon and my name both derive from the same thing.  One of them is a bad quasi-pun, and the other I've made more obvious.
[image: http://totalannihilation.wikia.com/wiki/The_Can]

It's a [kbot](http://totalannihilation.wikia.com/wiki/Kbot).

Comment: The Can! I loved playing Total Annihilation back in the day.

Answer (score 3):

This is my avatar. I took this picture in early August in Jerusalem, I think in Yemin Moshe neighbourhood, one of the oldest neighbourhoods outside the walls of the Old City.

I like using as avatars pictures that are "mine" - I took them, or I'm in them, and they have enough meaning to me that they can represent something about me. My avatar is sort of my face, right?

A Pomegranate is a Jewish symbol, 1st Temple onwards. Now, being a Jew isn't the alpha and omega of my identity. But it's sort of the broth that lends a certain flavour to everything in it. (Identity is totally a soup.) So, having to choose one image to be my face across several different SEs, it seemed appropriate.

[image: Pomegranate]

Answer (score 2):

> my user name used to be my real-name. When I eventually decided to go at least a LITTLE harder to track down, I changed my avatar...

Same story here. I originally had no idea what I should keep my avatar as, and like many other, t was the pre-generated one.

THEN, I had a moment of I-love-retro-games and changed it to - you guessed it - Mario! Sadly, the image that I downloaded vanished from the internet and my Hard Disk mysteriously..

> Okay, maybe I deleted the copy of the image from the Hard Drive. :P

Then, I changed it to something more modern...

[image: INFINTY]

My real name is traceable only by my avatar. And only to those who have a good memory. You can try guessing!